# The standard \cup vs. the mathabx \cup

Tags: symbols

I'm interested in using the standard `\cup`, i.e. [image: plain \cup]
and the one given by importing the mathabx `\cup`
[image: mathabx \cup] in the same document.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I'd advise against doing this. The symbols are too similar. It would be difficult to read if you had both with different meanings.

Comment: I disagree.  In algebraic topology you need a symbol for union and something called the cup product.  Traditionally they are denoted by almost exactly the same product but it is clear from the context whether you're talking about union or cup product.  So for sake of keeping with the tradition I think it is a good idea to have e.g. plain `\cup` for union and the mathabx `\cup` for cup product.

Comment: I think that `\smile` looks better for a cup product, and is different enough from `\cup` that the two shouldn't get confused.

Comment: @John: just be careful that `\smile` is of type `\mathrel` whereas `\cup` is of type `\mathbin`, so, to get correct spacing, you should use something like `\newcommand{\cupproduct}{\mathbin{\smile}}`.

Comment: @John Palmieri's/Goutet, thanks! `\smile` is what worked for me, and it's simple, in that the `\cup` conflict is completely circumvented rather than resolved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\let\ltxcup\cup
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}

$\ltxcup \cup$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it continues to use the symbol from the second font instead of the first. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

Unlike @Herbert's solution, this solution does not change any math font. It just add an `\abxcup` we defined.

Some of the code is copied from `mathabx.sty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\abxcup}{\mathbin}{matha}{'131}
\begin{document}
$A\cup B \abxcup C$
\end{document}
```

And this code showed how to get the glyph slot:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\fonttable{matha10}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For those who want to do this with different symbols, note that you can also peruse the mathb10 and mathx10 font tables, and that you get the codes for \DeclareMathSymbol from the first row and first column of these tables (i.e., it's not the tiny number next to the symbol in the table). Don't forget to copy the correct code from mathabx.sty if you are using the b or x tables.