# too little space between the bar on the denominator and the horizontal line

Tags: accents, fractions

Please see below:

[image]

There is too little space between the horizontal line from `\frac` and the bar from `\bar{h_1}`. So, it is a little hard to read. Any alternative way to represent the upper bar? And, it is short too.

ADDED:
This is inline mode. In the display math mode, it is quite better. But in the inline math mode, it looks pretty bad, even with `\bar{h}_1`.

Comment: Can you add a minimum working example? My version of this in frac has naturally wider spaces, as you want. i.e. `\frac{\bar{p}_1}{\bar{p}_1 + \bar{h}_1}`.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt It was inline mode. Sorry I missed that explanation. See the added explanation.

Comment: May be you could re-write your fraction as `$\bar{p}_1/(\bar{p}_1 + \bar{h}_1)$` which would fit better with inline math.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are using inline math mode `$..$` as opposed to display mode `\[...\]`.  Here is the comparison of the output between the two:

[image]

with the second one producing better spacing.  To obtain that you need to either use one of the following

```
\[\frac{\bar{p}_1}{\bar{p}_1 + \bar{h}_1}\]

$\displaystyle \frac{\bar{p}_1}{\bar{p}_1 + \bar{h}_1}$

$\dfrac{\bar{p}_1}{\bar{p}_1 + \bar{h}_1}$
```

Note that `\dfrac` requires that the `amsmath` package be loaded, either by including it explictly `\usepackage{amsmath}`, or as part some other package that already includes `amsmath`, such `\usepackage{mathtools}`.

Here is the MWE. Note that the `center` environment was only used to simplify the image capture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
$\frac{\bar{p}_1}{\bar{p}_1 + \bar{h}_1}$
\end{center}

\[\frac{\bar{p}_1}{\bar{p}_1 + \bar{h}_1}\]

\begin{center}
$\displaystyle \frac{\bar{p}_1}{\bar{p}_1 + \bar{h}_1}$
\end{center}

\begin{center}
$\dfrac{\bar{p}_1}{\bar{p}_1 + \bar{h}_1}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

To make the bar wider you can use `\overline` as in:

```
$\dfrac{\overline{p}_1}{\overline{p}_1 + \overline{h}_1}$
```

or adapt the `xoverline` from [The \bar and \overline commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22100/the-bar-and-overline-commands) with which you can adjust the spacing:

```
$\dfrac{\xoverline{p}_1}{\xoverline{p}_1 + \xoverline{h}_1}$
```

or specify you want it wider with:

```
$\dfrac{\xoverline[1.25]{p}_1}{\xoverline[1.25]{p}_1 + \xoverline[1.25]{h}_1}$
```

Here is a comparison between `\bar{p}_1`, `\overline{p}_1`, `\xoverline[1.25]{p}_1}`, and `{\xoverline[1.50]{p}_1`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\myboxA
\newsavebox\myboxB
\newlength\mylenA

\newcommand*\xoverline[2][1.00]{%
    \sbox{\myboxA}{$\m@th#2$}%
    \setbox\myboxB\null% Phantom box
    \ht\myboxB=\ht\myboxA%
    \dp\myboxB=\dp\myboxA%
    \wd\myboxB=#1\wd\myboxA% Scale phantom
    \sbox\myboxB{$\m@th\overline{\copy\myboxB}$}%  Overlined phantom
    \setlength\mylenA{\the\wd\myboxA}%   calc width diff
    \addtolength\mylenA{-\the\wd\myboxB}%
    \ifdim\wd\myboxB<\wd\myboxA%
       \rlap{\hskip 0.5\mylenA\usebox\myboxB}{\usebox\myboxA}%
    \else
        \hskip -0.5\mylenA\rlap{\usebox\myboxA}{\hskip 0.5\mylenA\usebox\myboxB}%
    \fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
$\dfrac{\bar{p}_1}{\bar{p}_1 + \bar{h}_1}$\quad
$\dfrac{\overline{p}_1}{\overline{p}_1 + \overline{h}_1}$\quad
$\dfrac{\xoverline[1.25]{p}_1}{\xoverline[1.25]{p}_1 + \xoverline[1.25]{h}_1}$
$\dfrac{\xoverline[1.50]{p}_1}{\xoverline[1.50]{p}_1 + \xoverline[1.50]{h}_1}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would there be any method or alternative to make the space wider, without using the displaystyle? I probably need to use another accent, like hat.

Comment: See updated solution with `\overline` and `\xoverline`.

Comment: I don't think that using `\displaystyle` of `\dfrac` in in-line math mode is a good option; it breaks the normal separation between lines.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I don't think the problem is so much with the OP using inline math mode as with the fact that he/she should not be using a fraction style that's not suitable for inline math.

Comment: This is a good answer. Very thorough. Nice.

Answer (score 16):

It is possible to define your own fraction command. The [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides

```
\genfrac{<ldelim>}{<rdelim>}{<thickness>}{<mathmode>}{<num>}{<denom>}
```

This typesets the fraction using numerator `<num>` and denominator `<denom>` with a line thickness `<thickness>`. Left and right delimiters are possible by specifying `<ldelim>` and/or `<rdelim>`. The mathmode override is also possible via `<mathmode>` by specifying an integer value from 0-3, which select respectively `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`.

In the minimal example below I've defined `\myfrac[<gap>]{<num>}{<denom>}` which raises/lowers `<num>`/`<denom>` by `<gap>` using `\raisebox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\myfrac}[3][0pt]{\genfrac{}{}{}{}{\raisebox{#1}{$#2$}}{\raisebox{-#1}{$#3$}}}
\begin{document}
\centering
\verb!Text style! \par
$\frac{a}{b}\ \myfrac{a}{b}\ \myfrac[1pt]{a}{b}\ \myfrac[2pt]{a}{b}\ \myfrac[3pt]{a}{b}$

\bigskip

\verb!Display style! \par
\[\frac{a}{b}\ \myfrac{a}{b}\ \myfrac[1pt]{a}{b}\ \myfrac[2pt]{a}{b}\ \myfrac[3pt]{a}{b}\]
\end{document}​
```

Perhaps a modification of this might suit your needs here, or elsewhere. It would also be possible to use a better choice mechanism to scale the font appropriately. However, this answer just provides a proof-of-concept.

Comment: Nice addition! I always forget about `\genfrac`.

Comment: @Werner Ooold post, but still useful. Is it possible to use `\raisebox{}` inside a math mode? It gives me an error, but I'm not sure that's the problem.

Comment: @Andyc: Yes, but you'll have to force math mode again inside, and possibly reduce the size of the style. That is, `\raisebox{<len>}{$<style><math>$}`, where `<style>` is `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle`.

Comment: @Werner I have a question. Why the distance from the midline to numerator and denominator doesn't look like the same?

Comment: @juanuni: It's to accommodate for ascenders in the denominator.

Comment: @Werner and if I want those distances to look the same, what should be changed in the code?

Comment: @juanuni: Typically the descender depth is not the same as the ascender height, but you can try preceding content with `\mathstrut`.

Comment: @Werner thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

When in inline math mode, and especially when diacritics (such as `\bar{.}`) are involved, it's almost always preferable to replace an expression such as

```
$\frac{\bar{p}_1}{\bar{p}_1+\bar{h}_1}$
```

with its "inline fraction" form,

```
$\bar{p}_1 / (\bar{p}_1+\bar{h}_1)$
```

See, e.g., the TeXbook, pp. 139f., for Knuth's "endorsement" of this form for inline math usage. The two expressions look like this (deliberately enlarged to make the problem with the inline-fraction method more easily visible):

[image]

Of course, if a math expression containing fractions is in "display" format (i.e., on a line by itself), there's usually no reason or need to use the "inline fraction" form.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$\bar{h}_1$`. That should at least centre the bar above h, although probably not lower it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\bar{h}_1` instead. The bar doesn't belong to the subscript, just to the `h`.

Answer (score 0):

This is TikZ's way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\d{1.2} % length of fraction line
\draw 
(0,0)--+(0:\d)++(0:\d/2)
+(90:.2)  node{$\overline{p_1}$}
+(-90:.25) node{$\overline{p_1}+\overline{h_1}$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```