# Smaller fractions in displayed formulae?

Tags: fractions, displaystyle

How do you make script-sized fractions in display mode?

In certain cases, I find that `\frac`-based fractions are too large for my tastes in displayed formulae. For example, I feel that the fractions here stand out way too much compared to the exponents:

[image: standard display style]

I can hack a workaround by writing things like `\frac{_1}{^{24}}`, but that seems like too much trouble. The result, however, does look more like what I want:

[image: hacked display style]

Alternatively, I can force text styling by writing things like `{\textstyle\frac{1}{24}}`. This feels cleaner to me, but I'm not sure it looks as readable as the earlier hacked version because the fractions are tighter vertically (great for text mode but a bit much for display mode).

[image: display mode using textstyle]

What would you do?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}

\[ \cos x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n}
= 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{24}x^4 - \frac{1}{720}x^6 + \cdots \]

\[ \cos x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n}
= 1 - \frac{_1}{^2}x^2 + \frac{_1}{^{24}}x^4 - \frac{_1}{^{720}}x^6 + \cdots \]

\[ \cos x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n}
= 1 - {\textstyle\frac{1}{2}}x^2 + {\textstyle\frac{1}{24}}x^4
- {\textstyle\frac{1}{720}}x^6 + \cdots \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Werner gave you a good answer, and I agree with you that the smaller ones look better. **Off-topic:** You should as well use `\dotsb` instead of `\cdots` to obtain proper spacing of the dots. I suppose you have to load `amsmath` for this command.

Comment: @tohecz: I don't see any difference with the `\dotsb` and `\cdots` either at the end, or in the middle of the equation.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\tfrac` or `\dfrac` constructs to forcibly write a fraction in `t`ext or `d`isplay style. In [`amsmath.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsmath.sty), these macros are defined via `\genfrac`

```
\newcommand{\dfrac}{\genfrac{}{}{}0}
\newcommand{\tfrac}{\genfrac{}{}{}1}
```

with the token `0`/`1` setting the math style to `\displaystyle`/`\textstyle` (`2` is for `\scriptstyle`; `3` is for `\scriptscriptstyle`, for what it's worth).

Here's a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\cos x &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n}
= 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{24}x^4 - \frac{1}{720}x^6 + \dotsb\\[2\baselineskip]
\cos x &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n}
= 1 - \dfrac{1}{2}x^2 + \dfrac{1}{24}x^4 - \dfrac{1}{720}x^6 + \dotsb \\[2\baselineskip]
\cos x &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \tfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n}
= 1 - \tfrac{1}{2}x^2 + \tfrac{1}{24}x^4 - \tfrac{1}{720}x^6 + \dotsb
\end{align*}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Just as Werner says, these are what you're looking for.

Comment: It would be probably better to show a usage example; as it stands the answer seems to say that one has to do those definition in their file.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just insert the command `\textstyle` to the right of the `&=` divider? That way, you'd also get a smaller `\sum` symbol, i.e., it wouldn't look nearly so overbearingly large relative to the rest of the material on the RHS of the equations.

Comment: @Mico: That's suggested by PhilippeGoutet in his answer. I think the question may have been more general than that.

Comment: A full API description may help someone: `\genfrac{<left parenthesis>}{<right parenthesis>}{<fraction line thickness>}{<display / text / scriptscript>}{<top element>}{<bottom element>}`.

Comment: @Atcold: Yes, I've done it [elsewhere](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34243/5764)...

Comment: You can use also `\tfrac {}{}`. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 12):

For optimal readability of the source code, you can just use `\textstyle` once and get the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[ \cos x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n}
= \textstyle 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{24}x^4 - \frac{1}{720}x^6 + \cdots \]

\end{document}
```

If in another context don't want the `\textstyle` to propagate, you can put everything inside braces:

```
{\textstyle 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{24}x^4 - \frac{1}{720}x^6 + \cdots}
```

This being said, in your example, using display fractions would be more coherent as you already have one inside the sum giving the cosine. Generally, it's not a good idea to have display and text fractions so close to each other in the same equation.

Comment: I don't think you need to be too worried about limiting the scope of the `\textstyle` command. In an `align` environment, for instance, the scope of this command ends automatically at every alignment tab (`&`) and at every line break. :-)

Comment: Or `\scriptstyle` for even smaller equations (useful for inline equations)

Answer (score 7):

A more general way is to use `\scalebox` from package `graphicx` and define your own macros.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}

\begin{document}

\def\hmath#1{\text{\scalebox{1.6}{$#1$}}}
\def\lmath#1{\text{\scalebox{1.4}{$#1$}}}
\def\mmath#1{\text{\scalebox{1.2}{$#1$}}}
\def\smath#1{\text{\scalebox{.8}{$#1$}}}

\def\hfrac#1#2{\hmath{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\lfrac#1#2{\lmath{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\mfrac#1#2{\mmath{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\sfrac#1#2{\smath{\frac{#1}{#2}}}

\def\pow{^\mmath}

Sizes: Huge , Large , Medium , Normal , Small

Displayed fractions: $\displaystyle \hfrac{x^k}{k!} = \lfrac{x^k}{k!} = \mfrac{x^k}{k!} = \frac{x^k}{k!} = \sfrac{x^k}{k!}$

Inline fractions: $\hfrac{x^k}{k!} = \lfrac{x^k}{k!} = \mfrac{x^k}{k!} = \frac{x^k}{k!} = \sfrac{x^k}{k!}$

Displayed exponents (normal,small): $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} e \pow {\frac{1}{2}\int f(x)\ dx} = \sfrac{dy}{dx} e ^ {\frac{1}{2}\int f(x)\ dx}$

Inline exponents (medium,normal): $\mfrac{dy}{dx} e \pow {\frac{1}{2}\int f(x)\ dx} = \frac{dy}{dx} e ^ {\frac{1}{2}\int f(x)\ dx}$

Displayed combinations (medium,normal): $\displaystyle \mfrac{e \pow {k\ln(x)}}{\sqrt{2\pi k}{(\mfrac{k}{e})} \pow k} = \frac{e^{k\ln(x)}}{\sqrt{2\pi k}{(\frac{k}{e})}^k}$

Inline combinations (medium,normal): $\mfrac{e \pow {k\ln(x)}}{\sqrt{2\pi k}{(\mfrac{k}{e})} \pow k} = \frac{e^{k\ln(x)}}{\sqrt{2\pi k}{(\frac{k}{e})}^k}$

Displayed series (normal): $\displaystyle \cos x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{24}x^4 - \frac{1}{720}x^6 + \cdots$

Displayed series (small): $\displaystyle \cos x = \smath{\sum_{n=0}^\infty} \sfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n} = 1 - \sfrac{1}{2}x^2 + \sfrac{1}{24}x^4 - \sfrac{1}{720}x^6 + \cdots$

Inline series (medium): $\cos x = \mmath\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n} = 1 - \mfrac{1}{2}x^2 + \mfrac{1}{24}x^4 - \mfrac{1}{720}x^6 + \cdots$

Inline series (normal): $\cos x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{24}x^4 - \frac{1}{720}x^6 + \cdots$

Convergent series: $\hmath{ 1 = \dfrac{1}{2} + \smath{ \dfrac{1}{4} + \smath{ \dfrac{1}{8} + \smath{ \dfrac{1}{16} + \smath{ \dfrac{1}{32} + \smath{ \dfrac{1}{64} + \smath{ \dfrac{1}{128} } } } } } } }$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent. I found a scalebox of 1.4 pretty good to display the PDF of a normal distribution (``\frac`` and ``\dfrac`` left me dissatisfied): ``\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2\pi}} ~ e^{\lfrac{-(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}``

Comment: @PatrickT: Thanks! By the way on Math SE, which does not support `\scalebox`, I use `\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}` instead, which works even though it's invalid. The valid LaTeX would be `\def\lfrac#1#2{\text{\large$\frac{#1}{#2}$}}` and there are some differences compared with `\mfrac`. But personally I frequently use `\exp` for the exponential function, since I don't like having fractional exponents that are floating in the middle of thin air. =)