# Vertical align of fractions inline and display mode (baseline?)

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, baseline, stackengine

I was checking the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34243/14423,)

for make a small fraction. I get the fraction but I noticed that there is a variation in the vertical alignment in display mode and inline mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\smath}[1]{\text{\scalebox{0.95}{$#1$}}}

\newcommand{\myfrac}[3][0pt]{\belowbaseline[-.65\baselineskip]{\smath{\genfrac{}{}{}{3}{\raisebox{#1}{$#2$}}{\raisebox{-#1}{$#3$}}}}}


\begin{document}
$\tanh\Bigl(\myfrac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr)$ 

\begin{align}
    \tanh\Bigl(\myfrac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

As you can see in display mode the fraction is moved up a little bit. This doesn't happen with `equation` environment nor `\[ \]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: \frac works fine.  Nor is \scalebox the culprit. This looks llike a bug in \genfrac (stackengine).

Comment: Oh well, I was looking for a small frac, because that I defined another "frac". I add information.

Comment: @JohnKormylo -- `genfrac` is defined in `amsmath`; I don't think it's redefined in `stackengine`.

Comment: @juanuni -- `align` should give exactly the same result as `equation`.  But I`d be inclined to use `\dfrac` instead of trying to define something else.

Comment: @barbarabeeton well I was looking for another small fraction, just that. Maybe I shouldn't try with small fraction in display mode.

Comment: There's also `\tfrac` ("t" for "text-sized").  See the `amsmath` user guide for examples (`texdoc amsldoc`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton yeah, but in my case `\tfrac`alters the space between lines in which it appears.

Comment: Huh?  `\dfrac` can sometimes push adjacent lines of text apart but the result of `\tfrac` is almost always small enough to fit within any reasonable baselines.  And it certainly is with the particular numerator and denominator you show in your example.  (But those are definitely smaller with `\tfrac` than what you show.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton well in my case is needed use `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` for the parenthesis with `\tfrac`.  In such a situation, the space between lines is altered, in my case. if I use `\bigl` and `\bigr` the fraction is bigger than parenthesis.

Comment: I've just tested this again.  `\dfrac` definitely needs the `\Big` parentheses, but `\tfrac` does not; the parentheses come just to the bottom of the denominator, and that is preferable to parentheses that are too large.  (Long experience and familiarity with editorial practices of a math publisher.)  And `\dfrac` by itself could cause the baselines to spread in text, depending on what is in the previous and following lines.  I still recommend `\tfrac`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton indeed `\tfrac` is a good option, but in my case with `stix2` package, `\tfrac` is bigger than `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`. Then, I switch `b` to `B`, but ocurrs the situation with space between lines. I would like to show the packages that I am using to find myself in that situation but this comes out of the query made.

Comment: Sadly, I can't help with `stix2`.  (It's frustrating.)  That information should have been made clear in your question.

Comment: Well, the situation in my question (vertical alignment) ocurrs with or without `stix2` package. The problem with space between lines is another question. In any case, I appreciate your time and interest.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The `equation` and `amsmath` environments **do not** always typeset the same way.  This question is a prime example.  The `amsmath` environments redefine the value of `\baselineskip`.  Since this OP's definition makes use of that value, the results vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the definition of `\myfrac` makes use of `\baselineskip`, whose value is reset in `amsmath` environments.  The solution?  Use `\normalbaselineskip` in the definition of `\myfrac` instead.

In fact, the default baselineskip for long stacks in the `stackengine` package is `\normalbaselineskip`, for precisely this reason.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\smath}[1]{\text{\scalebox{0.95}{$#1$}}}

\newcommand{\myfrac}[3][0pt]{\belowbaseline[-.65\baselineskip]{\smath{\genfrac{}{}{}{3}{\raisebox{#1}{$#2$}}{\raisebox{-#1}{$#3$}}}}}
\begin{document}
OK with non-amsmath
\[
    \tanh\Bigl(\myfrac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr)---\the\baselineskip
\]
In vertical alignment error with amsmath
\begin{align}
    \tanh\Bigl(\myfrac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr)---\the\baselineskip
\end{align}
Why? amsmath redefines \textbackslash baselineskip.\\
Solution? Use \textbackslash normalbaselineskip
\renewcommand{\myfrac}[3][0pt]{\belowbaseline[-.65\normalbaselineskip]{\smath{\genfrac{}{}{}{3}{\raisebox{#1}{$#2$}}{\raisebox{-#1}{$#3$}}}}}%
\begin{align}
    \tanh\Bigl(\myfrac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr)---\the\normalbaselineskip
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good diagnosis.  But in the third instance (presumably using `\normalbaselineskip`), the fraction line appears to actually cut through the top of the 2.  (In all instances, I think it's too close, but assume that's subjective. But intersecting can't be correct.)  However, the fraction line is definitely in the same vertical position as the math axis, which is what is wanted.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That is how the OP defined it to begin with, to get a close fraction.  I didn't pick up on that, but my reading of the question was that it was all about why the vertical shift occurred. I'll see if it is just font hinting, or actual

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have confirmed that your perception arises from the resolution of the image.  Under zoom, all denominators lie at the same relative position to the fraction bar.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thanks a lot.For the fraction line a put `\mathstrut` inside each `\raisebox` just before `$2$` and `$3$`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

While `\scalebox{0.95}{...}` is not a major problem `\scalebox{0.5}{...}` would be.  When you scale an image, only one point is not moved, which for `\scalebox` turns out to be the left baseline.

In the following I move the baseline to the center, scale it, then move the baseline back again.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{stackengine}

\fboxsep=0pt

\newcommand{\smath}[1]{\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\ht\strutbox-0.5\dp\strutbox}%
  {\scalebox{0.5}{\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\dp\strutbox-0.5\ht\strutbox}{$#1$}}}}

\newcommand{\myfrac}[3][0pt]{\smath{\tfrac{#2}{#3}}}

\begin{document}
$\tanh\Bigl(\myfrac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr) {\displaystyle \tanh\Bigl(\myfrac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr)}$

\begin{align}
    \tanh\Bigl(\myfrac{\alpha}{2}\Bigr)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate your time to write an answer. Your suggestion, elegant by the way, doesn't go in the direction of my question.In your suggestion I was trying with `\scalebox{0.75}{...}` and without `\Big` for parenthesis. I saw the fraction and the parenthesis was aligned at the bottom of the line. I was looking for move up the fraction a little bit so the fraction and parenthesis was centered vertically (I hope write this adequately). Because that I used `\belowbaseline[-.65\baselineskip]{{...}` and  I noticed that inline mode and with `align` environment the vertical shift isn't the same, and

Comment: ... that's what I was trying to solve.  I hope I have written well because English is not my native language.