# Graph about diode and operation point

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, circuitikz, axis

Good Evenning, I want draw this graph that has 2 graph, I use the tikzpicture package and axis.

A graph is a signal input(left), and anotar is signal output (below).

I want replicate this graph.[image]
And just I did this graphic, the blue point is a point operation.
[image]

This is my code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines= middle, xlabel={$V[v]$}, ylabel={$I$}, xlabel style={above right},ylabel style={above left}, xmin= 0, xmax = 10, ymin=0, ymax = 0.001, y post scale = 1.5]
      \addplot[domain= 0:10, samples = 100, thick,green] {((-0.0001)*x)+0.001)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.1,0)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.19,0.000001)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.29,0.000001)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.36,0.000004)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.40,0.00001)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.40,0.00002)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.45,0.000025)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.46,0.000034)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.45,0.000045)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.48,0.000052)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.50,0.00015)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.50,0.00025)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.57,0.00034)};
      \addplot[blue, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.60,0.00094)};
      \draw (axis cs: 0.1,0) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.19,0.000001) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.29,0.000001) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.36,0.000004) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.40,0.00001) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.40,0.00002) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.45,0.000025) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.46,0.000034) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.45,0.000045) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.48,0.000052) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.50,0.00015) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.50,0.00025) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.57,0.00034) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.60,0.00094) circle [radius=1];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I have something like that somewhere, tomorrow I'll try to find it and post. I am quite sure I had to use a fake curve for the diode - not-so-exponential because otherwise it is very difficult to see anything on the x-axis.

Comment: Thank you bro, is very important. I´m beginner in LaTeX.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

This is (an extract) of a beamer presentation I have done for the same topic you are asking.

Note, however, that:

1. this is quite advanced Ti*k*Z/`pgfplots` usage; I advise you to start with the `pgfplots` and Ti*k*Z (and if you need it, `circuitikz`) tutorials *before* digging into this code;
2. this is a `beamer` presentation, so there is the added complexity of the overlays to obtain the graph construction step-by-step; again, there are very nice tutorials around for beamer too;
3. yes, the learning curve of these tools **is steep**, so if you want to avoid frustration, follow the tutorial path (or give up and use some other tool );
4. the Ebers-Moll curve is fake. The real one is too steep *a*) to stay into the math limits of `pgfplots` and *b*) to produce anything really readable (reality is hard...);
5. I am not sure all the preamble is really needed, I trimmed this down from a big presentation.

So, the code is here. I use styles a lot to avoid repeating myself.

```latex
%%%
\documentclass[10pt,
,t %% top by default
,aspectratio=169 %%
,fleqn % left aligned equations
]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%%
\usepackage{mathtools}
%% siunitx setup
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\textmu}{\ensuremath{\upmu}}
\renewcommand{\textohm}{\ensuremath{\Upomega}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all, retain-explicit-plus, range-phrase= --,
exponent-product=\cdot, per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, fit, arrows.meta,
backgrounds, tikzmark, overlay-beamer-styles}
% circuits
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzsetstyle{romano}
\tikzset{>=Stealth}
%
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!50!black}
\colorlet{darkblue}{blue!50!black}
%
%% common macros here: subscript D is too big for my tastes
\newcommand{\vD}{v_{\scriptscriptstyle D}}
\newcommand{\VDQ}{V_{DQ}}
\newcommand{\vDtot}{v_{\scriptscriptstyle D\mathrm{tot}}}
\newcommand{\iD}{i_{\scriptscriptstyle D}}
\newcommand{\IDQ}{I_{DQ}}
\newcommand{\iDtot}{i_{\scriptscriptstyle D\mathrm{tot}}}
\newcommand{\eq}{=}%not needed in recent circuitikz
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34243/38080
\newcommand{\openfrac}[3][4pt]{\genfrac{}{}{}{}{%
  \raisebox{#1}{$#2$}}{\raisebox{-#1}{$#3$}}}
%% presentation data starts here
%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=superpdiodo]
  \frametitle{Diode small signal}
  \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth, T]
    \begin{column}{.38\linewidth}
      \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.9, transform shape, ]
        \draw (0,0) to[sV, v<=$v_s(t)\eq\Delta E$, ] ++(0,-2)
        to [battery2, invert, l=$E$] ++(0, -1)
        node[ground](GND){};
        \draw (0,0) to [R=$R_s$, -*] ++(3,0) node[above]{$\vD$} coordinate(vd);
        \draw (vd) to [D*, l=D, f=$\iD$] (vd|-GND) node[ground]{};
        \begin{scope}[red, overlay, visible on=<2->]
          \draw[decoration={brace}, decorate] (-.5,-3.5) -- ++(0,3)
            node[midway, left]{$E_{\mathrm{tot}}$};
        \end{scope}
      \end{circuitikz}
    \end{column}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{column}{.58\linewidth}
      % second column
      \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \begin{axis}[
          width=8cm, height=5cm,
          xmin=0, xmax=1,
          ymin=0, ymax=11,
          domain=0:1,
          axis x line = center,
          axis y line = center,
          axis line style = {thick, gray},
          enlarge x limits,
          enlarge y limits,
          xlabel = {$\vD$},
          % every axis x label/.append style = {below, gray},
          ylabel = {$\iD$},
          legend style = {nodes={right, font=\scriptsize},
            at={(0.05,0.6)}, anchor=west},
          clip mode = individual,
          ]
          % notes that the values are fake to stay into PGF math
          \addplot[thick, smooth, name path=diodef] {1e-3*exp(x/0.1)};
          %
          \only<2->{
            \addplot[red, samples=2, name path=load1 ] {6 - 6*x};
            \path (0,6) coordinate(deltaE pos) node[left, red, overlay]{$E_\mathrm{tot}$};
            \path[red, overlay] (0.8, 8) node[anchor=west, inner sep=1pt, fill=white](F)
              {$E_{\mathrm{tot}}=R_s\iD + \vD$};
            \draw[red, overlay, ->] (F.west) -- (0.6,3);

            \path [name intersections={of=diodef and load1}] (intersection-1)
              node[circ]{} coordinate(P1);
            \draw [red, dashed] (P1|-0,0) coordinate(deltaid pos) -- (P1) --
              (P1-|0,0) coordinate(deltavd pos);
          }
          %
          \only<3->{
            \addplot[blue, samples=2, name path=load2 ] {7 - 6*x};
            \path [name intersections={of=diodef and load2}] (intersection-1)
              node[circ]{} coordinate(P2);
            \draw [blue, dashed] (P2|-0,0) -- (P2) -- (P2-|0,0);
            %
            \addplot[darkgreen, samples=2, name path=load3 ] {5 - 6*x};
            \path [name intersections={of=diodef and load3}] (intersection-1)
              node[circ]{} coordinate(P3);
            \draw [darkgreen, dashed] (P3|-0,0) -- (P3) -- (P3-|0,0);
            % vstubs for sinusoidal
            \draw [thin, dashed, blue] (0,7) -- (0.2,7);
            \draw [thin, dashed, blue] (0,5) -- (0.2,5);
          }
        \end{axis}
        \pgfplotsset{minivgraph/.style={
            width=2.5cm, height=1cm, scale only axis,
            xmin=0, xmax=1000, domain=0:1000, samples=50, smooth,
            ymin=-1.1, ymax=1.1,
            axis x line = center, axis y line=center,
            xticklabel = \empty,
            yticklabel = \empty,
            every axis x label/.append style={right},
            every axis y label/.append style={at={(0.5,1)},
              anchor=center, inner sep=1pt},
            xlabel=$t$,
        }}
        \only<4->{
          \begin{axis}[at=(deltaE pos), anchor=west, blue,
            minivgraph,
            ylabel=$\Delta E\eq v_s(t)$,
            ]
            \addplot [thick] {0.55*sin(x)};
          \end{axis}
        }
        \only<5->{
          \begin{axis}[at=(deltavd pos), anchor=west, darkgreen,
            minivgraph,
            ylabel=$\Delta \iD$,
            ]
            \addplot [thick] {0.45*sin(x)};
          \end{axis}
          \begin{axis}[at=(deltaid pos), rotate=-90, anchor=north, red, overlay,
            minivgraph,
            width=2cm, xmax=800,
            ylabel=$\Delta \vD$,
            every axis x label/.append style={below},
            every axis y label/.append style={at={(1,1)},
              anchor=center, inner sep=1pt},
            ]
            \addplot [thick] {0.55*sin(x)};
          \end{axis}
        }
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \[
    \iD = f(\vD) = I_0\biggl(e^{\openfrac{\vD}{V_T}}-1\biggr),
    \quad V_T=\SI{25.9}{\mV} \text{ at \SI{300}{\kelvin}}
  \]
  \[
    \vD\gg V_T \Rightarrow \iD \approx I_0e^{{\vD}/{V_T}}
  \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bro, yes, this Is a graph, Is a simple circuit, thank.

Comment: @JoseGLopez sorry, I don't understand your comment... I hope the answer is useful for you.