# \bar vs. \overline - when to use what, semantically?

Tags: math-mode, accents, semantics

Following the question "[The \bar and \overline commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22100/the-bar-and-overline-commands)" which is simply about the lengths of both, I'd like to know when to use `\bar` and when to use `\overline` from a semantically viewpoint.

I always used `\bar`, because up until now I only had single letter mean values to type. But now I came to a problem where I needed a wider "bar".

Then I just tried

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \[ \bar{a} \overline{a} \]
  \[ \bar{abc} \overline{abc} \]
\end{document}
```

where one can see that they also differ in position (`\overline` is lower), and also in thickness (`\overline` is thicker).

So, the question here is:

**What does `\bar` represent semantically? And when to choose it over `\overline` and vice versa?**

Comment: For wider bars you can use [my `\widebar` command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253) (shameless plug).

Answer (score 129, accepted):

*Semantically*, don't use either.  Use `\conj`, or `\mean`, or `\variant` or whatever the overline is *meant* to mean.  Then in your preamble, do:

```
\newcommand*\conj[1]{\bar{#1}}
\newcommand*\mean[1]{\bar{#1}}
```

Then:

1. Your document *source* becomes readable: you can determine the meaning right there and then.
2. Your document becomes more flexible: if you decide to denote complex conjugation by a star instead you can simply redefine `\conj` without worrying about changing what `\mean` does.
3. You can change from `\bar` to `\overline` on a whim and don't have to make that crucial decision now.

Comment: while the suggestion to use a "meaningful" command is excellent, the expansion would have to be more complicated to allow for single or multiple-letter arguments.  since the original question mentioned both, that should be addressed in your answer.

Comment: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection"

Comment: as mentioned by @barbarabeeton, this fails for a term like $B^d_D(0)$, overline does well on the other hand

Comment: Ok, but after making this new command, which should I use for mean, `\bar` or `\overline`?

Comment: @endolith The question specifically asked about which to use _semanitcally_ and for that the answer is "neither". If you want to know which the semantic definition should expand to, then it depends on several factors but the question linked in the question is where I'd start reading.

Comment: in other words, you are saying we should always use bar. so what's the point of overline then?

Comment: @user313032 I do not say that. I have no opinion on bar vs overline _typographically_.  However, the question asked about _semantic_ use, and that is what I've answered.

Comment: Which implies that if you type some else's text without fully understanding it (e.g., because you're just a typist or the text is junk), DO use `\bar` or `\overline`, and DON'T try anything semantic from the beginning.

Answer (score 22):

`\bar{a}` can mean just "another thing" like if you used `a'` or `\tilde{a}` or `\diamondclub`. You never use `\overline` for this.

However, if you denote an operation like complex conjugation, reversal, set closure or whatever, you can use whichever you want. You found out that somehow (to some people) `\bar{a}` seems "too subtle" for this purpose, and you can use the reasonable solution proposed in the other question. This goes along the fact that in this case, things like `\overline{x+y}`, `\overline{2U+V}`, `\overline{a_1, a_2 \cdots, a_n}` have their meaning as well.

Answer (score 20):

I have indeed observed a difference between `\overline` and `\bar`:
Having 3 lines of formula in one `\align` environment, using overline in combination with a 3rd power like this:

```
\overline{b}^3
```

causes the 3rd equation to need more vertical space and the 3rd equation
was shifted down a bit, which looked quite disturbing.
Using

```
\bar{b}^3
```

solved the Problem, so all three equations have the same vertical distance now.

The following code produces a little sheet of pdf which illustrates some differences between bar and overline:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  $\begin{array}{r}
    a+b+c\\
    a+b^3+c\\
    a+\overline{b}+c\\
    a+\overline{b}^3+c\\
    a+\bar{b}+c\\
    a+\bar{b}^3+c\\
    a+\overline{b^3}+c\\
    a+\bar{b^3}+c\\
    a+b+c
  \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the different distances of equations and the different commutation behavior of the `\bar` and `\overline` commands with the power command.

Finally, I recommend always using `\bar` for single numbers for example.
For complex conjugation of many numbers `\overline` of course is the appropriate choice.

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer is great. The major practical considerations I’ve run into are when I’ve wanted to either put a bar over multiple symbols or put wide bars over two distinct adjacent symbols that do not run together.

When you need a single bar over multiple symbols, `\bar` does not work, and you want `\overline`.  Unicode introduces a third bar-above accent, which in most math fonts is between the two in width.  This is available in `unicode-math` as `\overbar`.

If I want a wide bar that does not run into consecutive symbols, I’ve had success with:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand\widebar[1]{\mathop{\overline{#1}}}

\begin{document}
  \( \widebar{\mathbb{A}} \widebar{\mathbb{B}} \widebar{\mathbb{AB}} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Wide bar example]

If this fouls up superscripts and subscripts, making them appear above and below, change to `\mathop{\overline{#1}}\nolimits`.

This does not require `unicode-math`, by the way.