# Create a weightier (bold) \bar

Tags: math-mode, bold, stacking-symbols

Here's my MWE, with my question embedded:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
The bar over the $E$ in $\bar E$ is a little too faint for my
taste. Or should I just go with the default?
\end{document}
```

I'm fine with the length, so don't need the answer to [The \bar and \overline commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22100/the-bar-and-overline-commands/22134#22134)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a bold bar:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%%% For the example we keep the old \bar
\let\oldbar\bar % this is not necessary in the real application

%%% Define a new math font
\DeclareSymbolFont{boldoperators}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{boldoperators}{bold}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\edef\bar{\unexpanded{\protect\mathaccentV{bar}}\number\symboldoperators16}

\begin{document}

$\oldbar{E}\bar{E}$

{\boldmath$\oldbar{E}\bar{E}$}

\end{document}
```

This is based on the fact that `\bar` is redefined by `amsmath` to expand to

```
\protect\mathaccentV{bar}016
```

where `0` is the mathgroup where the symbol is taken from. We redefine it to use a newly allocated symbol font.

[image]