# Overline thickness

Tags: math-mode, rules

Is there a way in latex to change the vertical thickness (height) of the line generated by the `\overline` command?

```
\[
\overline{\overline{A \vee B}} = \overline{\overline{A} \wedge \overline{B}}
\]
```

Comment: Here is that message again: [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The \bar and \overline commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22100/the-bar-and-overline-commands)

Comment: @PeterGrill: [The `\bar` and `\overline` commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22100/the-bar-and-overline-commands) is about the *width* of the line, not the *height/thickness*.

Comment: @Werner: i dont know if i wrote it correctly, but i need change height of overline (vertical thickness)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### TeX

The default rule thickness θ is 0.4pt in TeX.
An `\overline` formula is set as `\vbox`:

- At the top is a kern of θ
- The bar follows with thickness θ
- The gap to the formula has height 3θ
- The formula follows.

θ is taken from fontdimen 8 of math font family 3. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  $\overline{abc}$
  \fontdimen8\textfont3=5pt
  $\overline{abc}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result TeX]

As can be seen, also the gap between the line and the formula changes with the thickness of the line (even with factor 3).

### LuaTeX/LuaLaTeX

LuaTeX makes the parameters configurable:

- `\Umathoverbarkern`: the white space above the line
- `\Umathoverbarrule`: line thickness
- `\Umathoverbarvgap`: the gap between the line and the formula

These values can be set for all eight math styles. LuaTeX also makes the
cramped styles available as:

- `\crampeddisplaystyle`
- `\crampedtextstyle`
- `\crampedscriptstyle`
- `\crampedscriptscriptstyle`

In cramped styles, used for formulas below bars (`\overline`, `\sqrt`, denominator in fractions), the exponents are set lower than usual.

LuaLaTeX adds a prefix `luatex` to LuaTeX's new primitives (to avoid name clashes). The following example sets `\Umathoverbarrule` in all eight styles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\setumath}[2]{%
  \csname luatexUmath#1\endcsname\displaystyle=#2\relax
  \csname luatexUmath#1\endcsname\luatexcrampeddisplaystyle=#2\relax
  \csname luatexUmath#1\endcsname\textstyle=#2\relax
  \csname luatexUmath#1\endcsname\luatexcrampedtextstyle=#2\relax
  \csname luatexUmath#1\endcsname\scriptstyle=#2\relax
  \csname luatexUmath#1\endcsname\luatexcrampedscriptstyle=#2\relax
  \csname luatexUmath#1\endcsname\scriptscriptstyle=#2\relax
  \csname luatexUmath#1\endcsname\luatexcrampedscriptscriptstyle=#2\relax
}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
    \csname check@mathfonts\endcsname
    \setumath{overbarrule}{#1}%
    $\overline{abc}$ % additional space
  }
  \test{.1pt}
  \test{.4pt}
  \test{1.6pt}
  \test{6.4pt}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result LuaLaTeX]

Comment: The `\setumath` works only for the second math (move the `\test{6.4pt}` to the begin to see, also your image shows that the first two lines have the same height). One has to call `\check@mathfonts` first.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, answer updated by adding `\check@mathfonts`.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than trying to contend with the existing definition, one could design their own, using stacks.  Here the `1.2\LMpt` is the vertical offset above the item of the overline, and `.4\LMpt` is the rule thickness.  As part of a `\ThisStyle` argument, an `\LMpt` is 1pt it `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle`, but proportionately reduced in `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`, as shown in the MWE.

One may or may not wish to stack a `\mathop` around the definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\myoverline#1{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{1.2\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{\rule{\wd0}{.4\LMpt}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}%
}}
\begin{document}
\[
\myoverline{\myoverline{A \vee B}} = \myoverline{\myoverline{A} \wedge
\myoverline{B}}
\]\[
\scriptscriptstyle
\myoverline{\myoverline{A \vee B}} = \myoverline{\myoverline{A} \wedge
\myoverline{B}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For example, here, we change the offset to `1.4\LMpt`, and the thickness to `.6\LMpt`:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The following answer is not a solution, but an easy trick suitable for some purposes (and *not* for all purposes). The `\overbracket{}` command in package *mathtools* has two arguments (rule thickness and bracket height):

```
\overbracket[〈rule thickness〉] [〈bracket height〉]{〈arg〉}
```

Suppose you set a rule thickness smaller than *x* pt. If you set the bracket height at *-x* pt then you get a line (values between 0 and minus the rule thickness also yield a line, but small anomalies could be visible at its extremes).

The solution is not strictly "correct", since the resulting line is slightly shorter than that of `\overline{}` and the distance between lines shall not be the same that in `\overline{\overline{}}`. But for some purposes the outcome can be similar enough.

In the following minimal working example two commands are defined: in `\myov{}` the thickness is set in the preamble; in `\myovline{}` there is an argument for it. I set the bracket height at -1pt because all the thicknesses in the MWE are below 1pt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\myov}[1]{\overbracket[0.65pt][-1pt]{#1}}
\newcommand*{\myovline}[2]{\overbracket[#2][-1pt]{#1}}
\begin{document}
$$\overline{A \vee B} = \overline{\overline{A} \wedge \overline{A}}$$ % Default thickness = 0.4 pt
$$\myovline{A \vee B}{0.4pt} = \myovline{\myovline{A}{0.4pt} \wedge \myovline{A}{0.4pt}}{0.4pt}$$
$$\myovline{A \vee B}{0.6pt} = \myovline{\myovline{A}{0.8pt} \wedge \myovline{A}{0.8pt}}{0.8pt}$$
$$\myov{A \vee B} = \myov{\myov{A} \wedge \myov{A}}$$
\end{document}
```

[image]