# \overline with weight of overlined text

Tags: fontsize, bold

I want to overline  (/bar) a character. Depending on the font weight and font size of this character, though, I want the overline to be of different thickness – it should scale with both font size and font weight.

How can I accomplish this?

Ideally, the distance between the overline and the character should also be (auto-)configurable. Smaller characters need more space between character and overline, relatively, than taller ones.

#### Background

Our physics experiment is called PANDA, with an `\overline` on top of the P.
While this looks decently enough for usual text, as soon PANDA is printed bold or in a bigger text size (section headings), it starts looking wrong.
[image: PANDAs]
(The first always is a `\overline{P}`, the second `\bar{P}`. [Here's the ShareLatex code (section 1)](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/53bd3de7f119471916cfa08d?r=495e8f7e&rs=ps&rm=d).)

#### Attempts

I searched around and fiddled a bit, but I did not get the look I'm looking for. At section 2 of above ShareLatex file I summarized the three main possibilities I found.

In the fntguide (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/fntguide.pdf, page 8) I also found the internal macros which hold the current font style. `\f@series` is responsible for the font thickness. I know too little TeX, though, for writing an `\if` using macro around this variable.

Comment: My answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167954/overline-thickness/167995#167995 deals with the problem of variation with font size, but does not address variation with font weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an overline with a thickness depending on the weight: it checks if `\f@series` contains `b` and, in this case, it adds a small amount of thickness. With the values in the code below, the standard rule is 0.04em which becomes 0.06em for boldface; change the `0.02` in the definition of `\panda@check@b` to adapt it to your taste.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\panda}{\oP ANDA}
\newcommand{\oP}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{%
      ##\cr
      \kern.04em % start a bit to the right
      \leaders\hrule height \pandarulewidth\hfill % the rule
      \kern.1em % stop a bit to the left
      \cr
      \noalign{\vskip0.1ex}
      P\cr
    }%
  }%
  \sbox0{P\kern0ptA}%
  \sbox2{PA}%
  \dimen0=\wd2
  \advance\dimen0 -\wd0
  \kern\dimen0 % the kern between P and A
}
\makeatletter
\def\pandarulewidth{%
  \dimexpr0.04em+0\panda@add em\relax
}
\def\panda@add{\expandafter\panda@check@b\f@series b.\@nil}
\def\panda@check@b#1b#2\@nil{\if.#2\else0.02\fi} % adjust at will
\makeatother

\begin{document}

PANDA

\panda

\textbf{\panda}

\LARGE\panda

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a more complicated version that also works for slanted fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\panda}{\oP ANDA}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oP}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \edef\panda@slant{\strip@pt\fontdimen1\font}%
    \halign{%
      ##\cr
      \kern\panda@slant\fontcharht\font`P
      \kern.04em % start a bit to the right
      \leaders\hrule height \pandarulewidth\hfill % the rule
      \kern.1em % stop a bit to the left
      \kern-\fontcharic\font`P
      \cr
      \noalign{\vskip0.1ex}
      P\cr
    }%
  }%
  \sbox\z@{P\kern0ptA}%
  \sbox\tw@{PA}%
  \dimen\z@=\wd\tw@
  \advance\dimen\z@ -\wd\z@
  \kern\dimen\z@ % the kern between P and A
}
\def\pandarulewidth{%
  \dimexpr0.04em+0\panda@add em\relax
}
\def\panda@add{\expandafter\panda@check@b\f@series b.\@nil}
\def\panda@check@b#1b#2\@nil{\if.#2\else0.02\fi} % adjust at will
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\panda

\textit{\panda}

\textbf{\panda}

\itshape\LARGE\panda

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another refinement for taking into account the sidebearings of sans serif fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\panda}{\oP ANDA}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oP}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \edef\panda@slant{\strip@pt\fontdimen1\font}%
    \halign{%
      ##\cr
      \kern\panda@slant\fontcharht\font`P
      \kern.04em % start a bit to the right
      \edef\sfdefault{\sfdefault}% sorry for the hack
      \ifx\f@family\sfdefault \kern.06em\fi % some more kerning for sans serif
      \leaders\hrule height \pandarulewidth\hfill % the rule
      \kern.1em % stop a bit to the left
      \kern-\fontcharic\font`P
      \cr
      \noalign{\vskip0.1ex}
      P\cr
    }%
  }%
  \sbox\z@{P\kern0ptA}%
  \sbox\tw@{PA}%
  \dimen\z@=\wd\tw@
  \advance\dimen\z@ -\wd\z@
  \kern\dimen\z@ % the kern between P and A
}
\def\pandarulewidth{%
  \dimexpr0.04em+0\panda@add em\relax
}
\def\panda@add{\expandafter\panda@check@b\f@series b.\@nil}
\def\panda@check@b#1b#2\@nil{\if.#2\else0.02\fi} % adjust at will
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\panda

\textit{\panda}

\textbf{\panda}

\LARGE\textit{\panda}

\textsf{\panda}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is really great!  
A small esthetic problem I encountered with sans serif fonts. Here's an example: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/53bd40c1f119471916cfa0ec?r=495e8f7e&rs=ps&rm=d – the bar starts a bit too much to the left. Is there a way to fix this automatically?

I made a [small sty file](https://gist.github.com/AndiH/b7bc9275c371cb995a95) from your code where I introduced a manual offset – but having it automatically would be much better.

Comment: @AndiH I added some more kerning for sans serif