# Unicode-math and fractions

Tags: unicode-math

I try to use `unicode-math` with Linux Libertine, and the result is in general working fine. In my opnion, the main problem is fractions. Consider the below example where there is far too much space *above* the horizontal line. Is there a way to fix this?

I know that Linux Libertine is not intended for use with math, but it might be that this particular issue could be solved.

(BTW, I compiled my document using LuaLaTeX.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,num}]{Linux Libertine O Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Linux Libertine O Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Linux Libertine O Bold Italic}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \frac{27}{81},\qquad \frac{\pi^2}{6}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the value like this (see also [Overline thickness](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167954/overline-thickness/167957#167957) and the documentation of luatex for more commands):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,num}]{Linux Libertine O Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Linux Libertine O Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Linux Libertine O Bold Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{Latin Modern Math} %last font should be a math font

\begin{document}
\makeatletter\check@mathfonts\makeatother %to force mathsetup
\luatexUmathfractionnumup\displaystyle=2pt

\[
  \frac{27}{81},\qquad \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution, thought it would be best to adjust `\luatexUmathfractiondenomdown` similarly.

Comment: @Gaussler: You asked about the space above the line ... I leave the rest of the finetuning (including which values please you best) to you,

Comment: Indeed, you did exactly what I asked. I wrote the comment to make future readers aware of the existence of the denominator counterpart.

Comment: Also, I was not aware that LuaTeX provided such advanced control for math layout directly through primitives. So in principle, if I go through all of them and adjust them one by one, I get the equivalent of a Microsoft Math Table for any font I want?