# How to add a massive bar on the letters?

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

At the moment I have an output with `\bar{...}` command as

[image]

and I want something that extends over the entire term preferably without redefining the original command.

Comment: all through what?

Comment: Use `\overline` instead of `\bar`.  The `\bar` accent is meant to be used for single letters only.

Comment: @HenriMenke Sorry I should have mentioned overline is a bit too thick or is there a way to thin the overline?

Comment: @Johannes_B over the entire term not through sorry

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167954

Comment: By "massive", do you mean to refer to the length or the thickness of the bar?

Comment: @QuantumDart You cannot thin `\overline`, because it is a primitive command.  You can write a macro which does similar things with a variable line thickness, though.

Comment: @QuantumDart Maybe you should edit your question, so that people can directly see what you need without having to read through all these comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write

```
$\overline{\mathbf{M}_{\mathbf{2}}(\mathbf{q}_{\mathbf{b}})}$
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a macro `\voverline` which has a variable rule width and separation from the content.  These parameters are called `\voverlinesep` and `\voverlinewidth`.  They can be adjusted via `\setlength`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\voverlinesep
\newlength\voverlinewidth
\setlength\voverlinesep{1pt}
\setlength\voverlinewidth{.1pt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\voverline[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@voverline{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@voverline[2]{%
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \rule[\dimexpr\ht0+\voverlinesep]{\wd0}{\voverlinewidth}%
  \llap{\box0}
}
\begin{document}
$\overline{\mathbf{M}_{\mathbf{2}}(\mathbf{q}_{\mathbf{b}})}$
versus
$\voverline{\mathbf{M}_{\mathbf{2}}(\mathbf{q}_{\mathbf{b}})}$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Actually, `\setlength\voverlinesep{1.2pt}` would fit better, because the separation to the formula is 3 times the line thickness (default 0.4pt) for `\overline`.