# XeTeX + \overline: Which \fontdimen’s are used?

Tags: fonts, xetex, opentype

**Edit**: This question has been *thoroughly* reedited to highlight the problem at hand.

I am trying to mimic `\overline` to create similar symbols. According to [Overline thickness](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167954/164314) on TeX.SX, and Appendix D in the [`unicode-math` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf), I gathered the following information:

```
|      |        Type 1       | OpenType + LuaTeX | OpenType + XeTeX |
|------|---------------------|-------------------|------------------|
| kern |     fontdim 8 fam 3 | \Umathoverbarkern | fontdim 55 fam 2 |
| rule |     fontdim 8 fam 3 | \Umathoverbarrule | fontdim 54 fam 2 |
| vgap | 3 × fontdim 8 fam 3 | \Umathoverbarvgap | fontdim 53 fam 2 |
```

However, when I tried to implement this, I found out that the following is *actually* used for OpenType under XeTeX:

```
|      |   OpenType + XeTeX   |
|------|----------------------|
| kern |     fontdim 54 fam 2 |
| rule |     fontdim 54 fam 2 |
| vgap | 3 × fontdim 54 fam 2 |
```

Furthermore, the above “wrong” table does not work well with [Fira Math](https://ctan.org/pkg/firamath) on CTAN, although this may be a font problem (see [Fira Math Issue 29](https://github.com/firamath/firamath/issues/29)).

## Question

Is this a XeTeX engine bug? How can I find out which font dimensions are being used? XeTeX does not seem to provide any reference manual on these subjects.

#### MWE

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX % <- Everything lines up perfectly
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX %  <- Not good for Fira Math
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[version=L]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[version=P]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[version=T]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[version=F]{Fira Math}
\makeatletter
\def\test@overbarkern@fontdimen{55}% Not used. XeTeX mistake?
\def\test@overbarrule@fontdimen{54}
\def\test@overbarvgap@fontdimen{53}% Not used. XeTeX mistake?
\def\test@@family{2}
\def\test@overbarkern#1{\fontdimen\test@overbarrule@fontdimen
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont
    \else\ifx#1\textstyle\textfont
      \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont
        \else\scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi \test@@family}
\def\test@overbarrule#1{\fontdimen\test@overbarrule@fontdimen
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont
    \else\ifx#1\textstyle\textfont
      \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont
        \else\scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi \test@@family}
\def\test@overbarvgap#1{\thr@@\fontdimen\test@overbarrule@fontdimen
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont
    \else\ifx#1\textstyle\textfont
      \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont
        \else\scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi \test@@family}
\ifx\XeTeXcharclass\@undefined
  % LuaTeX primitives
  \global\let\test@overbarkern\Umathoverbarkern
  \global\let\test@overbarrule\Umathoverbarrule
  \global\let\test@overbarvgap\Umathoverbarvgap
\fi
\newcommand*\test{\mathpalette\test@stuff{xyz}}
\def\test@stuff#1#2{%
  \vbox{\hrule\@height0.1\p@\hbox{$\m@th#1\overline{#2}$}}\,%
  \vbox{%
    \hrule\@height0.1\p@
    \kern\test@overbarkern#1%
    \hrule\@height\test@overbarrule#1%
    \hbox{\vbox{%
      \kern\test@overbarvgap#1%
      \hbox{$\m@th#1#2$}%
    }}%
  },%
}
\newcommand*\dotest[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \mathversion{#1}%
  $\displaystyle\test$ $\textstyle\test$ $\scriptstyle\test$ $\scriptscriptstyle\test$%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\dotest{L}\par
\dotest{P}\par
\dotest{T}\par
\dotest{F}
\end{document}
```

XeLaTeX output:
[image: output]

With LuaLaTeX, everything lines up perfectly no matter which math font is used.

Comment: luatex and xetex are different here (xetex uses (new) numbered params and luatex has named font params) which are you using? (xetex, I guess)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I am using XeTeX. I took another wild guess: With LuaTeX, `\__um_overbar_vgap:N #1` yields the correct amount of vertical space across all fonts in my example. However, with XeTeX, it appears that the vertical space should be `3 \__um_overbar_rule:N #1`, which works for all fonts *but* Fira Math. This appears to be the long standing problem with XeTeX using the wrong font dimensions…

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have thoroughly reedited my question. Do you think that the problem at hand is a XeTeX engine bug? If so, where should one report such an issue?

Comment: the xetex issue tracker is https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/  I may look at your revised example later.