# How to show a wide bar over a letter?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I want to have a wide bar over `XY` but it just shows a small bar. Any idea?
[image]

```
\item In the standard $(x,y)$ coordinate plane, point $X$ has coordinates $(-4,0)$ and point $Y$ has coordinates $(0,-8)$. What is the coordinates of the midpoint of $\bar{XY}$?\hfill
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $(-6,-1)$     
    \item $(-2,-4)$ 
    \item $(0,2)$ 
    \item $(2,4)$ 
    \item $(6,-1)$          
    \end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Did you try `\overline{XY}`?

Comment: See [The `\bar` and `\overline` commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22100/5764).

Comment: Nice to see you dear Mona. +1

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To get an *overline*, well, just use the `\overline` TeX primitive!

```
\overline{XY}
```

You might want to add some semantic meaning. E.g., define a macro

```
\newcommand*\midpoint[1]{\overline{#1}}
```

and use as

```
\midpoint{XY}
```

or something similar.

Comment: A semantic meaning does not make sense here because `overline` is really clear.