# How does one modify \xoverline for subscripts/superscripts?

Tags: math-mode

The `\xoverline` command (see [the-bar-and-overline-commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22100/the-bar-and-overline-commands)) works beautifully except that it assumes normalsize. So it blows up the size of subscripts as in

```
$A_{\xoverline{K}}$ vs $A_{\overline{K}}$
```

Comment: My question is, how do you fix this? The size of the subscript should not be changed by adding an overline to the subscript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try  [Hendrik Vogt's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package?lq=1) (thanks, Hendrik!), which I have adopted in the form of a small
.sty file, `widebar.sty`:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% IDENTIFICATION
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{widebar}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Defines a \widebar command, similar to\widehat.
%%% May have problems with indices
%%% Comes from Hendrik Vogt's answerhere : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package/60253#60253
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{amsmath}

\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
%Enable nesting of accents:
    \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
%If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
    \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
%Determine the italic correction:
    \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
    \dimen@\wd\tw@
    \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
%Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
    \divide\dimen@ 3
    \@tempdima\wd\tw@
    \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
%Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
    \divide\@tempdima 10
    \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
%Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
%The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
    \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
    \if#31
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
      \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
%Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
      \let\final@kern#2%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
      \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
    \else
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
%The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
  \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \else
%If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
%a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
      \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Here is a minimal test code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{widebar} 

\begin{document}

\[ \widebar{\mathbf A}_{\widebar{K}_{\widebar L}} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter


\newsavebox\myboxA
\newsavebox\myboxB
\newlength\mylenA

\newcommand*\xoverline[2][0.75]{%
    \sbox{\myboxA}{$\m@th#2$}%
    \setbox\myboxB\null% Phantom box
    \ht\myboxB=\ht\myboxA%
    \dp\myboxB=\dp\myboxA%
    \wd\myboxB=#1\wd\myboxA% Scale phantom
    \sbox\myboxB{$\m@th\overline{\copy\myboxB}$}%  Overlined phantom
    \setlength\mylenA{\the\wd\myboxA}%   calc width diff
    \addtolength\mylenA{-\the\wd\myboxB}%
    \ifdim\wd\myboxB<\wd\myboxA%
       \rlap{\hskip 0.5\mylenA\usebox\myboxB}{\usebox\myboxA}%
    \else
        \hskip -0.5\mylenA\rlap{\usebox\myboxA}{\hskip 0.5\mylenA\usebox\myboxB}%
    \fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

 $A_{\xoverline{K}}$ vs $A_{\overline{K}}$ 


 $A_{\text{\xoverline{K}}}$ vs $A_{\overline{K}}$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This (putting the xoverlined-subscript inside "\text") works well too. Thanks!