# ugly \overline on some characters

Tags: math-mode

The code at the end gives

[image]

As you can see, `\widehat` and `\widetilde` give good result, but `\overline`
looks bad on some characters, especially for `A`, `I` and `J`.
What commands or workarounds can solve this problem, please.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
$ \overline{A} \ \overline{I} \ \overline{J} $ \\
$ \widetilde{A} \ \widetilde{I} \ \widetilde{J} $ \\
$ \widehat{A} \ \widehat{I} \ \widehat{J} $ \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22100/55879) asks for differently sized `\overline` commands. It might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Henrik Vogt's code in an answer to a similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package/60253#60253):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
    \rel@kern{0.8}%
    \overline{\rel@kern{-0.8}\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.2}}%
    \rel@kern{-0.2}%
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
  \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

    \[ \widebar{A}\ \widebar I\ \widebar J\]%
    \[ \widetilde{A}\ \widetilde I\ \widetilde J\]%
    \[ \widehat{A}\ \widehat I\ \widehat J\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]