# Subscript after \underline in math mode

Tags: subscripts, underline

I would like to put a subscript after a character with multiple underlines in the math mode but ignoring the underlines. How can I do it?

Consider this picture:
[image: vertical subscript positions]
I would like the subscript to have the vertical position of the element with respect to the character. Here is the code the produced the picture:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ulem,amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}
\(C_{\text{c}}, 
\underline{\bm{C}}_{\text{c}}, 
\underline{\underline{\bm{C}}}_{\text{c}}, 
\uuline{\bm{C}}_{\text{c}}\)
\end{document}
```

Edit: Would be superb if the underline was limited to the width of the character.

Comment: What about the horizontal position? For the vertical position the easiest thing here is to use an empty group, e.g. `\underline{\bm{C}}{}_{\text{c}}`.

Comment: Thank you, @campa! I am so stupid :). I updated the post about to reflect on my preference about horizontal position.

Comment: `\smash{\underline{\underline{\bm{C}}}}_{\text{c}}` as a partially satisfying way

Comment: Thanks, @jfbu, but I fail to see how it is different from the empty group solution, proposed above.

Comment: @campa, if adjusting the length of the underline is too much work, could you please submit your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22134/107114), the following satisfied my requirements, including additional:

```
\newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\underline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}
\newcommand{\uubar}[1]{\ubar{\ubar{#1}}}
```