# Ugly `\overline` raised to a power

Tags: math-mode

I'm denoting the complement of the closure of the set `$A$` by `$\overline{A}^C$`.  This looks ugly, though (the `C` is too high up and not far enough to the right)--might there be any quick fixes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this closer?

```
$\overline{A}\,^C$
```

It pushes to the right as `\,` is a thin space and lowers it as it is the space atom that is being superscripted not the capital A.

Comment: This is great.  Somehow, not only does the `\,` space push the `C` to the right, but it also lowers it so that its height matches `A^C`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

What about this?

```
$\smash{\overline{A}}\vphantom{A}^C$
```

(`\smash` typesets its argument and "hides" it as if it had zero height; `\vphantom` puts a zero-width, invisible "something" of height equal to its argument's height (and depth, for that matter).)

Comment: Actually, with `\vphantom{a}` you'd obtain the same output. Only if it gets _taller_ than `A`, you'd see a difference.

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand*\bar[1]{\rlap{$\smash{\overline{#1}}$}\phantom{#1}}

\begin{document}
 $\overline{A}^C \bar{A}^C$.
\end{document}
```

Basically, I delete all the dimensions of the `\overline`d symbol and place a box of the base symbol's size where the superscript can find it.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, the `\overline` looks ugly for a second reason: it extends way too much to the left:

[image: ugly image]

I'd use some appropriate kerns to make the `\overline` shorter. For lowering the `C`, you could use `{}^C` (left version in the image below), but you can also fine-tune it with a rule of zero width (right version):

[image: better image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\mkern4.5mu\overline{\mkern-4.5mu A}{}^C$
$\mkern4.5mu\overline{\mkern-4.5mu A}\rule{0pt}{1.6ex}^C$
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to manually find out the appropriate kerns for the `\overline`, give the `\widebar` command from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253) a try (shameless plug).