# Space between rows in a table

Tags: tables, spacing

I created a table in LaTeX, however, I can not put a space after the first row. As you can see the bar of X mean overlaps the `\hline`. I tried `\\[1pt]` after `\hline`, but it produced much more space than I expected. The code I wrote is shown below. 
[image: Table]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 0.3in}c@{\hskip 0.2in} c@{\hskip 0.2in} c@{\hskip 0.2in} c@{\hskip 0.3in} l}
\hline
& $\delta$ & $\varepsilon$ & $\eta$ & $w$ & $c_{i}~(i=1,...,k)$\\ 
\hline
$\overline{y}_{RW(st)}=\overline{y}_{st} \dfrac{\overline{X}}{w\overline{x}_{st}+(1-w)\overline{X}}$ & -1 & -1 & -1 & & $(-w)^{i}$\\[10pt]
$\overline{y}_{Gu(st)}=\overline{y}_{st}\left[w\dfrac{\overline{X}}{\overline{x}_{st}}+(1-w)\left(\dfrac{\overline{X}}{\overline{x}_{st}}\right)^{2}\right]$ & -1 & -1 & 1 & & $(-1)^{i}[i(1-w)+1]$\\

....

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: The code snippet needs to be completed so its an MWE.

Comment: Related question: [spacing - Column and row padding in tables - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IMHO the most convenient way is to use the `booktabs` package to add extra white space around the horizontal lines which are called according to their position `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 0.3in}c@{\hskip 0.2in} c@{\hskip 0.2in} c@{\hskip 0.2in} c@{\hskip 0.3in} l}
\toprule
 & $\delta$ & $\varepsilon$ & $\eta$ & $w$ & $c_{i}~(i=1,...,k)$\\ 
 \midrule
$\overline{y}_{RW(st)}=\overline{y}_{st} \dfrac{\overline{X}}{w\overline{x}_{st}+(1-w)\overline{X}}$ & -1 & -1 & -1 & & $(-w)^{i}$\\[10pt]
$\overline{y}_{Gu(st)}=\overline{y}_{st}\left[w\dfrac{\overline{X}}{\overline{x}_{st}}+(1-w)\left(\dfrac{\overline{X}}{\overline{x}_{st}}\right)^{2}\right]$ & -1 & -1 & 1 & & $(-1)^{i}[i(1-w)+1]$\\    
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: booktabs-MWE]

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to use the approach suggested by @hakaze, viz., to use the rule-drawing commands of the `booktabs` package, you could inserts a "strut" -- a typographic term as well as a construction/engineering term -- to create more vertical clearance *above* (for a "top strut") and/or *below* (for a "bottom strut") the point where the strut is inserted.

The following modified form of your MWE shows how this may be done. Note that I've inserted a top strut in the numerator of the first big math expression and a bottom strut in the subscript of the denominator in one of the terms in second big math expression. For good measure, I've also thrown in a couple of these struts in the header line.

In addition, I've (i) used an `array` instead of a `tabular` environment (because all of the environment's contents seem to be in math mode and because the default amount of intercolumn white space is slightly larger for `array` environments), (ii) replaced the heavy-looking `\overline` instructions with `\bar` instructions, and (iii) used explicit size-setting instructions for the large round parentheses and square brackets. (The sizes that result from `\left` and `\right` instructions are just too large.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % top strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.1ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % bottom strut

\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{l rrr c l}
\hline
& \delta & \varepsilon & \eta & w & c_{i}\ (i=1,\dots,k)\Tstrut\Bstrut \\ 
\hline
\bar{y}_{RW(st)}=\bar{y}_{st} \dfrac{\bar{X}\Tstrut}{w\bar{x}_{st}+(1-w)\bar{X}} 
  & -1 & -1 & -1 & & (-w)^{i}\\[10pt]
\bar{y}_{Gu(st)}=\bar{y}_{st}\biggl[
w\dfrac{\bar{X}}{\bar{x}_{st}}+(1-w) 
\biggl(\dfrac{\bar{X}}{\bar{x}_{st\Bstrut}} \biggr)^{2}\,
\biggr] 
  & -1 & -1 & 1 & & (-1)^{i}[i(1-w)+1]\\
\hline
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree that the `\overline`s are too heavy, but I think `\bar{X}` is much too light. You might be interested in [this `\widebar` command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253) I coded.

Comment: @HendrikVogt - thanks! Your `\widebar` command would indeed appear to occupy a happy middle ground between `\overline` and `\bar`.