# Adding row spacing to a longtable?

Tags: tables, spacing, longtable

I want to add some extra spacing between the rows of my `longtable` - but not for every table of the entire document, just one of them. I've tried to use the `\\[dist]` mechanism, but with surprising (at least to me) results: The distance is only added if the rightmost cell of the row being ended is the one with the greatest height:

[image: spacing issue]

What can I do to add the space regardless of the individual height of the cells?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{longtable}    

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
first & first \\
nospace & nospace \\
short & short \\[6pt]
sep & sep \\
short & long long long long long long \\[6pt]
sep & sep \\
long long long long long long & short \\[6pt]
last & last \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can add `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}` immediately before `\begin{longtable}`, and this will affect just that one table.  Of course, 1.4 is a proportion.  Get as much space as you want :)

Also, you could use the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package.  Take a look at this post:

[Space between rows in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65919/space-between-rows-in-a-table)

Note: Possible duplicate of [How to set the space between rows in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102996/how-to-set-the-space-between-rows-in-a-table)