# Increasing the space between two rows?

Tags: tables, spacing, booktabs

This is possible duplicate of [increasing space between two rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65919/space-between-rows-in-a-table). But because of two many math expression there, I could not possibly understand it. Regrets.

I would like to increase the space between two rows so that table can be filled manually using pen or pencil. Here is MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} p{5cm}}
\toprule 
Item & Quantity \\
\midrule 
Widgets & \dotfill \\ 
Gadgets & \dotfill \\
\midrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Widgets & \dotfill \\[10pt]
Gadgets & \dotfill \\ `  which uses the optional argument to `\\ ` or, alternately, `\midrule 
&\\
Widgets & \dotfill \\
&\\
Gadgets & \dotfill \\
\midrule ` which manually adds blank rows

Comment: @ Steven B. Segletes it increased the space between 2nd and 3rd row, but not between first and second row.

Comment: Here is what I did: \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} p{5cm}}
\toprule 
Item & Quantity \\ [10pt]
\midrule 
Widgets & \dotfill \\ [10pt] 
Gadgets & \dotfill \\
\midrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Comment: Related question: [spacing - Column and row padding in tables - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here I show 3 ways:

1. the optional argument to `\\[]`
2. Add blank lines manually
3. Add a custom strut to lines where needed.

Approach 1 will not work following a `\modrule`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
%\begin{table}
\centering
Use optional argument to \verb|\\|, but can't be used for line after a
\verb|\midrule|

\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} p{5cm}}
\toprule 
Item & Quantity \\
\midrule 
Widgets & \dotfill \\[10pt]
Gadgets & \dotfill \\
\midrule 
\end{tabular}
%\end{table}

\bigskip

Add blank lines manually

\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} p{5cm}}
\toprule 
Item & Quantity \\
\midrule 
&\\
Widgets & \dotfill \\
&\\
Gadgets & \dotfill \\
\midrule 
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Add a strut where needed

\def\mystrut{\rule{0pt}{2\normalbaselineskip}}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} p{5cm}}
\toprule 
Item & Quantity \\
\midrule 
Widgets\mystrut & \dotfill \\
Gadgets\mystrut & \dotfill \\
\midrule 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first option is the simplest, doesn't even require use of additional packages.

Comment: The strut is the best because it doesn't mess with horizontal lines in the table.  Is there a way to make the strut go down as well as up?

Comment: @Andrea Yes, for example, `\def\mystrut{\rule[-\normalbaselineskip]{0pt}{2\normalbaselineskip}}`, using the optional argument.

Answer (score 26):

You can use `\addlinespace` from `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%% Sets page size and margins

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} p{5cm}}
\toprule
Item & Quantity \\
\midrule
\addlinespace[1cm]
Widgets & \dotfill \\
\addlinespace[0.8cm]
Gadgets & \dotfill \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Modify `arraystretch`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
{ % begin box to localize effect of arraystretch change
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3.0}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{5cm} p{5cm}}
        \toprule 
        Item & Quantity \\
        \midrule 
        Widgets & \dotfill \\ 
        Gadgets & \dotfill \\
        \midrule 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
} % end box
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Though the problem is it involves all the tables in a document.

Comment: Right @Vaibhav, and I edited to localize the change.  But it still adds space in unwanted areas, e.g., the header row.  The other answers are much better!