# How to *lower* an overline

Tags: math-mode, spacing, height, overline

My question is similar to [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370853/182603) [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102698/producing-several-overlines-of-the-same-height-throughout-a-formula), but all the solutions have been about *raising* the overline. In contrast, I would like to *lower* the overline so that it is the same height for all lowercase letters. For example, I'd like this

[image]

to look more like this

[image]

How could I do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{minimal}
\begin{document}
$\overline{a} + \overline{b}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, don't use the `minimal` class for examples, it's not meant for such applications.

Comment: What's it meant for then? I thought this was exactly its purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smash, but keep the height of the lowercase letter *and* of the symbol you're typesetting.

```
\newcommand{\lowoverline}[1]{%
  \overline{\smash{#1}\vphantom{x}}\vphantom{#1}%
}
```

Full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\lowoverline}[1]{%
  \overline{\smash{#1}\vphantom{x}}\vphantom{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\lowoverline{a}+\lowoverline{b}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can similarly define `\lowbar`, which I deem preferable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\lowoverline}[1]{%
  \overline{\smash{#1}\vphantom{x}}\vphantom{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\lowbar}[1]{%
  \bar{\smash{#1}\vphantom{x}}\vphantom{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\lowoverline{a}+\lowoverline{b}
\quad
\lowbar{a}+\lowbar{b}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

By smashing things. In the following example, the argument `b` is vertically smashed (its height doesn't count). The `\lowoverline` gets its height from the optional argument, which defaults to a. This argument is horizontally smashed and made invisible by `\phantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\lowoverline[2][a]{\ensuremath\overline{{\smash{#2}\vphantom{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\overline{a}\quad \lowoverline{b}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**Edited:** my original code used `\mathclap{\phantom{#1}}`, but Jordan Mitchell Barrett and egreg pointed out the simpler alternative `\vphantom{#1}`.

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it! :)

Comment: Why `\mathclap{\phantom{#1}}` when `\vphantom{#1}` suffices?

Comment: @egreg --- Indeed; see my comment to the OP's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\smash{b}` to set the height of `b` to zero, and then `\vphantom{a}` to make something with zero width and the height of an `a`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{minimal}
\newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{\smash{#1}\vphantom{a}}}

\begin{document}
$\overline{a} + \overline{b}$

$\ol{a} + \ol{b}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I always forget about `\vphantom`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\vphantom{#1}`?

Comment: @egreg: no, because you want the overline to be the same height as the "a", rather than whatever's provided.

Comment: OK, I explained wha I meant in my answer.