# \overline and \widehat with subscript

Tags: math-mode, symbols, subscripts

I would like to create commands to produce overlines (respectively wide hats or arrows) with a subscript at the end. The commands

```
\overline{X}^{1}   \widehat{X}^{2}  \overrightarrow{X}^{3}
```

do not suit my needs since the subscripts should be controlled by the overline (respectively wide hat, right arrow). Ideally I would like to have a command like

```
\myoverline_{1}{X}   \mywidehat_{2}{X}  \myoverrightarrow_{3}{X}
```

What would be the cleanest way to do so?

P.S. The closest thing I was able to find is this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110411/unusual-custom-math-accent/110413#110413).

**Update** Here is a picture of what I wish to obtain:

[image]

Comment: i'm unable to picture what you want from this description.  in the cited answer, the "superscripts" are actually set above the "decoration".  do you want your "subscripts" stacked below the over-accents, and then that whole construction stacked on top of what it's embellishing?  if you could draw a picture, and post it as a scan, that would be very helpful.

Comment: `\overline{X_1}`?

Comment: I think you meant *superscript* instead of *subscript*.

Comment: @kevin-c No, I mean subscript, the subscript is relative to the bar, not to the X.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: I see. It would be useful if you could add this piece of  information to the question (i.e. that `1` is a *subscript* to the overline).

Comment: I'm not sure the reader would understand that the little number is a subscript to the decoration rather than an exponent for the expression.

Comment: @egreg I agree with you and I hope that the comments have now clarified what I really meant. I was not familiar with the word "decoration", which I should have used. Please accept my apologies for being imprecise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach gives the subscript to the "overline" as you seemed to indicate.  With this implementation, the overline thickness is .4pt which can be changed. The bottom of the subscript is 1.5pt below the top of the argument.  The 2pt setting determines the vertical location of the overbar relative to the subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\subline[2]{\stackon[-1.5pt]{#1}{\rule[2pt]{\widthof{$#1$}}{.4pt}_{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
$A = \subline{X}{1} \subline{g}{2} \subline{Xyzq}{12}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For the widehat, I adopt a bit of a different approach, making added use of the `scalerel` package.  The parameter `\hatgap` gives the vertical gap between item and hat, and `\subdown` gives the relative placement of the subscript relative to the hat.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\hatgap{2pt}
\def\subdown{-2pt}
\newcommand\reallywidehat[2][]{%
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}%
\stackon[\hatgap]{#2}{%
\stretchto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{$#2$}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
    {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
}{0.5ex}% THIS SQUEEZES THE WEDGE TO 0.5ex HEIGHT
_{\smash{\belowbaseline[\subdown]{\scriptstyle#1}}}%
}}
\begin{document}
$\reallywidehat[1]{zbcdklm} \times
\reallywidehat[ijk]{zbcdefghijk} = 
\reallywidehat{zb}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The widehat EDIT is very loosely based on my solution at [Really wide hat symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol/101136#101136), though this implementation is superior to that one.

Comment: I like this solution. Is it possible to adapt it also for \widehat (and other decorations) ?

Comment: I tried using this but latex is complaing that "stackengine.sty" not found.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @MikhailKatz If your LaTeX installation doesn't load it automatically, it can be found at https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine

Answer (score 10):

your example looks enough like a symbol with a (raised) `\overline` and a superscript
to the base symbol that i'm going to construct that.

the second image might suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 $\overline{\mathrm{X}\vphantom{()}}^1
 \quad
 \smash{\overline{\mathrm{X}\vphantom{()}}}\vphantom{X}^1$
\end{document}
```