# How to indent formula in two different lines

Tags: math-mode, indentation, code

Please see the uploaded photo.

The formula is too long, so I have to let it breaks to the second line. However I want to indent the two formulas, so what should I do ?

Please help me. Thanks. 
[image]

Comment: Can you give minimal MWE or example of your code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? E.g., have you tried loading the `amsmath` package and using an `align*` environment? Please advise. (Aside: What does "Tuong tu" mean?)

Comment: You can use the `amsmath`package and with the environment `multline` and a couple of macros for control spacing (sich as `\quad`) you can easily but manually achieve it. The other option could be `align` as Mico suggests.

Comment: Thank you very much, juanuni, Mico and Aradnix. Tuong tu mean similarly., but `align*` did it well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for completeness, here's a solution that uses an `align*` environment.

Note that instead of using `\overline` to draw the horizontal bars above the four pairs of uppercase letters, a macro called `\widebar` is used. The code for the `\widebar` macro is copied from a posting by Hendrik Vogt. (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/5001 for the original contribution.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%% See the posting by Hendrik Vogt at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/5001
%%% for the source of the following code, which defines a "\widebar" macro

\makeatletter
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
%Enable nesting of accents:
    \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
%If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
    \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
%Determine the italic correction:
    \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
    \dimen@\wd\tw@
    \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
%Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
    \divide\dimen@ 3
    \@tempdima\wd\tw@
    \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
%Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
    \divide\@tempdima 10
    \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
%Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
%The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
    \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
    \if#31
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
      \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
%Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
      \let\final@kern#2%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
      \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
    \else
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
%The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
  \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \else
%If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
%a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
      \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\text{Similarly,}\quad 
\frac{b}{a+b}\widebar{FZ} +\frac{b}{c+b}\widebar{DX}
   &= \frac{abc}{(a+b)^2}-\frac{abc}{(c+b)^2}\,; \\
\frac{c}{b+c}\widebar{DX}+\frac{c}{a+c}\widebar{EY}
   &= \frac{abc}{(b+c)^2}-\frac{abc}{(a+c)^2}\,.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```