# How to match alignment of subscripts if one of main characters is \overline-d?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, subscripts

I can align dagger and non-dagger expressions using, for example, `$\psi_i^\dagger \psi_i^{\vphantom\dagger}$`.  How do I do the same for overlines, for example: in `$\overline{\psi}_i \psi_i$`, the subscript on the second `$\psi$` will not be at the same height as the first one.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you provide a working code in which those lines occur? I suspect something with `\smash`...

Comment: You should probably not be typing `\overline{\psi}_i` anyway; try `\bar{\psi}_i` instead. For sure, the subscript `i` in `\psi_i` has the same vertical position as in `\bar{\psi}_i`.

Comment: You may want to look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package for getting a wide bar, especially Leo Liu's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably not be typing `\overline{\psi}_i` anyway -- try `\bar{\psi}_i` instead. For sure, the subscript in `\psi_i` has the same vertical position as in `\bar{\psi}_i`.

If for some reason you simply must write `\overline{\psi}_i`, you should write `\psi^{}_i`, i.e., insert an empty superscript "atom", in order to get a conformable vertical position (though not a perfectly equal vertical position) of the subscript.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\bar{\psi}_i$ $\psi_i$ \quad $\overline{\psi}_i$ $\psi^{}_i$
\end{document}
```