# \bar and \overline

Tags: math-mode

If I write `$\bar{X}$` or `$\overline{X}$` the bar (or the rule) over X is smaller or longer than the width of X.
Is there any way to adjust the width?

Thank you in advance.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\bar{X}$ $\overline{X}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The slanting makes the correct length of the bar a little more complicate.
The following example measures the width of an upright X and uses this for the length of the bar. The solution also works for different math styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Xbar}{}%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\Xbar}{%
  \mathpalette\@Xbar{}%
}
\newcommand*{\@Xbar}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused (empty)
  \sbox0{$#1\mathrm{X}\m@th$}%
  \sbox2{$#1X\m@th$}%
  \rlap{%
    \hbox to\wd2{%
      \hfill
      $\overline{%
        \vrule width 0pt height\ht0 %
        \kern\wd0 %
      }$%
    }%
  }%
  \copy2 %
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\bar{X}$ $\overline{X}$

$\Xbar\scriptstyle\Xbar\scriptscriptstyle\Xbar$

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Just a question if I put \Xbar in chapter or section I get an error :

Comment: Missing number, treated as zero. ... }\copy 2 }_{n_2}$}{18}{subsection.1.12.4} in tableofcontents

Comment: @Haouam The macro was not robust and `\protect` was needed in front of `\Xbar`. The updated answer now uses `\DeclareRobustCommand` and `\Xbar` should work without an additional `\protect`.

Comment: Thank you , I have not noticed the update, It works fine !

Comment: I was trying to reproduce the format in my [statistics textbook](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Probability-Statistics-Applications-Engineering/dp/007246836X), and this looks like it exactly (the \Xbar in the bottom left). Thank you!

Comment: What does the star version of \DeclareRobustCommand means? It is not in the xparse documentation.

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand` is defined as `\newcommand` in the LaTeX kernel. The star form uses the plain TeX `\def`, the non-star form uses `\long\def` for the definition. With `\long`, the arguments can contain `\par` tokens, without `\long`, the defined macro throws an error, if it finds `\par` in an argument. Here, it does not matter much, because the macro is defined without arguments.

Comment: Aahh, I thought it was \DeclareDocumentCommand from xparse, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 4):

I need a bit shorter overlines for variables in boolean algebra to make clear that variables are separately inverted. I defined the following command:

```
\newcommand{\olsi}[1]{\,\overline{\!{#1}}} % overline short italic
```

It is special designed for variables that are typeset in italic, so it is not only above but rather above right. So upright characters need a different definition:

```
\newcommand{\ols}[1]{\mskip.5\thinmuskip\overline{\mskip-.5\thinmuskip {#1} \mskip-.5\thinmuskip}\mskip.5\thinmuskip} % overline short
```

Example:

```
$ \olsi{x+y} = \olsi{x}\olsi{y} $
```

is rendered as:

[image: example of short overlines]

I hope that helps.