# problem in tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have posted this question 
[\bar and \overline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314238/bar-and-overline/314242#314242)

When I put  `\Xbar` in  tableofcontents  I get this error :

Missing number, treated as zero. ... }\copy 2 }_{n_2}$}{18}{subsection.1.12.4}

what's wrong ?

Any advice ?

My MWE

```
\documenclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\Xbar}{%
\mathpalette\@Xbar{}% 

} 
\newcommand*{\@Xbar}[2]{%
 % #1: math style
 % #2: unused (empty)
\sbox0{$#1\mathrm{X}\m@th$}%  
\sbox2{$#1X\m@th$}%
\rlap{%
\hbox to\wd2{%
\hfill
$\overline{%
\vrule width 0pt height\ht0 %

\vrule width 0pt height\ht0 %
\kern\wd0 %
}$%
}%
}%
\copy2 %
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}



\tableofcontents

\section{Test of \texorpdfstring{$\Xbar_{n_1}$}{} and \texorpdfstring{$\Xbar_{n_2}{}}

\section{another section}
\section{Third section}
$\Xbar$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your example, there is errors not related to the issue.

Comment: Use `\protect\Xbar` when in a section title.

Comment: I used \protect without success I get this message error in my system (Miktex 2.9) :

Comment: ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.29 ... }\copy 2 }_{n_2}$}{18}{subsection.1.12.4}
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Comment: ! Color stack action is missing.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.29 ... }\copy 2 }_{n_2}$}{18}{subsection.1.12.4}
                                                  
The expected actions for \pdfcolorstack:
    set, push, pop, current
I'll ignore the color stack command.

Comment: my documentclass is book

Comment: try with new copy-paste of `\Xbar` and `\@Xbar` from [linked answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314238/bar-and-overline/314242#314242)

Comment: @Haouam If your document class is `book` then edit your original post and replace `\documenclass{article}` by `\documenclass{book}` in the given code.