# Colored underlining without affecting vertical spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing, color, ulem

I'm using the coloured underlining trick described in the [`ulem` package manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/ulem/ulem.pdf) (p.3). The underlining looks good, but interacts poorly with `align`-like environments, where (in contrast to `\uline`) it affects the height of the row:

[image]

It is possible to have a version of `\reduline` that, modulo colour, behaves as `\uline`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\reduline{\bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{red}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \uline{ABCD} + EFGH \\
  \reduline{ABCD} + EFGH \\
  ABCD + EFGH
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The accents package is preferable to put accents under mathematical symbols and doing this would be easy (but not from the cellphone I'm typing this on)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this works....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\reduline}[1]{{\color{red}\uline{{\color{black}#1}}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
    \uline{ABCD} + EFGH \\
    \reduline{ABCD} + EFGH \\
    ABCD + EFGH
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The trick seems doesn't allow line breaks in the inner text.  (I'm using it in a normal text paragraph)

Comment: I needed to add `\color{black}` to the end of the `\reduline` command for it to switch back to black outside the command.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{accents}


\newcommand{\redlb}[1]{{\color{red}\underaccent{\bar}{\color{black}#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  {A} + B \\
  \redlb{A} + B \\
  A + B
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Your red under-bar is wider than mine.  The author of the accents package questions the wisdom of using wide bars, but if you want one of those then you can find out [as an answer to a different question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package) how to accomplish that.  Strangely, wide tildes are easier.

**EDIT**

And here's how to get a wide tilde under accent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{accents}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wtilde}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{"65}

\newcommand{\redlb}[1]{{\color{red}\underaccent{\bar}{\color{black}#1}}}
\newcommand{\redwt}[1]{{\color{red}\underaccent{\wtilde}{\color{black}#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  A + B \\
  \redlb{A} + B \\
  \redwt{A} + B
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - however it's underlining that I need. Updated example code and PNG.

Comment: see new answer.