# Changing the color of special underlines with ulem

Tags: macros, color, ulem

I'm using the `ulem` package to produce different kinds of underlining, and want each underline style to be in a different color (so that the difference is visible whether you're viewing the document in black and white or not). The package documentation gives an example for how to define a colored version of the basic `\uline` command, which works just fine:

```
\newcommand\reduline{\bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{red}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}
```

What I'm having trouble with is creating new commands to give the other types of underlining colors, namely `\dashuline`, `\dotuline`, and `\uwave`, i.e. make one of them blue, one green, etc. The definition of these commands in `ulem.sty` is more complex than I understand, and I'm not sure how to plug them into the above format. Other underlining packages would be theoretically fine, but I do need a variety of underline shapes, which aren't predefined in `soul` for example, as far as I can tell.

Comment: For text with one color, see a quick and dirty solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325866.

Comment: Related...while this does not give different underline styles, it provides ways when the different underline colors partially overlap: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169189/highlighting-text-through-stacked-colored-underlines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a lot easier than you may think. As the documentation suggests, just look in `ulem.sty` and copy and modify the definitions (starting on line 211). Just insert a color changing command in the argument to `\markoverwith` in the definition you want to modify and that's it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
  \newcommand\reduline{\bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{red}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}
  \UL@protected\def\blueuwave{\leavevmode \bgroup 
    \ifdim \ULdepth=\maxdimen \ULdepth 3.5\p@
    \else \advance\ULdepth2\p@ 
    \fi \markoverwith{\lower\ULdepth\hbox{\textcolor{blue}{\sixly \char58}}}\ULon}
  \UL@protected\def\yellowdotuline{\leavevmode \bgroup 
    \UL@setULdepth
    \ifx\UL@on\UL@onin \advance\ULdepth2\p@\fi
    \markoverwith{\begingroup
       %\advance\ULdepth0.08ex 
       \lower\ULdepth\hbox{\kern.06em \textcolor{yellow}{.}\kern.04em}%
       \endgroup}%
    \ULon}
  \UL@protected\def\greendashuline{\leavevmode \bgroup 
    \UL@setULdepth
    \ifx\UL@on\UL@onin \advance\ULdepth2\p@\fi
    \markoverwith{\kern.13em
    \vtop{\color{green}\kern\ULdepth \hrule width .3em}%
    \kern.13em}\ULon}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\reduline{I am underlined in red.}

\blueuwave{I am underlined with blue waves.}

\yellowdotuline{I am underlined with yellow dots.}

\greendashuline{I am underlined with green dashes.}

I am not underlined at all.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thank you! The reason this wasn't transparent to me I think is just that it's unclear where the correct place to put the \textcolor{} call is in each of the definitions. In the ulem documentation's example, it's the first thing in the \markoverwith{} call, but in your definitions, I don't see a consistent location for it. Can you explain how you determined where the call goes in each different definition?

Comment: @JoshM Well, the argument to `\markoverwith` always consists of some spacing commands (adding horizontal space (like `\kern`) or shifting something vertically (like `\lower`)) together with one thing inserting the actual line (or dot). I just looked for that line insertion and put that into `\textcolor`. In the case of `\dashuline` putting the `\hrule` into `\textcolor` doesn't work, so I used `\color` instead (I could also have put the entire `\vtop` into `\textcolor`). I can see how these definitions can seem intimidating and incomprehensible, though. Don't worry about that for now.

Answer (score 3):

Just an simple wrap for convenience to support any predefined color:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{customdeepgreen}{HTML}{006A71}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\coloruline}[2]{%
        \newcommand\temp@reduline{\bgroup\markoverwith
            {\textcolor{#1}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}%
        \temp@reduline{#2}%
    }

    \newcommand{\coloruuline}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uuline{\leavevmode \bgroup
            \UL@setULdepth
            \ifx\UL@on\UL@onin \advance\ULdepth2.8\p@\fi
            \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\lower\ULdepth\hbox
                {\kern-.03em\vbox{\hrule width.2em\kern1\p@\hrule}\kern-.03em}}}%
        \ULon}%
        \temp@uuline{#2}%
    }

    \newcommand{\coloruwave}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uwave{\leavevmode \bgroup 
        \ifdim \ULdepth=\maxdimen \ULdepth 3.5\p@
        \else \advance\ULdepth2\p@ 
        \fi \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\lower\ULdepth\hbox{\sixly \char58}}}\ULon}
        \font\sixly=lasy6 % does not re-load if already loaded, so no memory drain.
        \temp@uwave{#2}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \coloruline{red}{I am underlined in red.}

    \coloruwave{blue}{I am underlined in blue waves.}
    
    \coloruuline{customdeepgreen}{I am double underlined in custom deep green.}

    I am not underlined at all.

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I obtain 2errors:

! Undefined control sequence.
\coloruwave #1#2->\UL@protected 
                                \def \temp@uwave {\leavevmode \bgroup \ifdim...
l.39 ...wave{blue}{I am underlined in blue waves.}

and 

! Undefined control sequence.
\coloruuline #1#2->\UL@protected 
                                 \def \temp@uuline {\leavevmode \bgroup \UL@...
l.41 ...m double underlined in custom deep green.}

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0


BUT.. after pulse twice ENTER I obtain the PDF.

Other people No errors.

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement over [mkpoli's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/562459/280044) that avoids some errors by changing the `\colorluline` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{customdeepgreen}{HTML}{006A71}

\makeatletter
% -------Changes made here-----------
\newcommand{\coloruline}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uline{\leavevmode \bgroup
            \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}%
        \ULon}%
        \temp@uline{#2}%
    }
%-----------------------------------

    \newcommand{\coloruuline}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uuline{\leavevmode \bgroup
            \UL@setULdepth
            \ifx\UL@on\UL@onin \advance\ULdepth2.8\p@\fi
            \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\lower\ULdepth\hbox
                {\kern-.03em\vbox{\hrule width.2em\kern1\p@\hrule}\kern-.03em}}}%
        \ULon}%
        \temp@uuline{#2}%
    }

    \newcommand{\coloruwave}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uwave{\leavevmode \bgroup 
        \ifdim \ULdepth=\maxdimen \ULdepth 3.5\p@
        \else \advance\ULdepth2\p@ 
        \fi \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\lower\ULdepth\hbox{\sixly \char58}}}\ULon}
        \font\sixly=lasy6 % does not re-load if already loaded, so no memory drain.
        \temp@uwave{#2}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \coloruline{red}{I am underlined in red.}

    \coloruwave{blue}{I am underlined in blue waves.}
    
    \coloruuline{customdeepgreen}{I am double underlined in custom deep green.}

    I am not underlined at all.

\end{document}
```