# Are there any similar package (or color ulem) to ulem package with color?

Tags: color, underline, ulem

Are there any similar packages (or color ulem) to the `ulem` package, with color, underline, sout, xout, dash underline, dot underline with color as parameter?

I found [this Q&A about changing the color of special underlines with ulem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530454/changing-the-color-of-special-underlines-with-ulem) months ago, and I like that solution, but I'd like:

- color as parameter
- sout, xout, dash underline and dot underline work well.
- even works well with a paragraph

[image]

---

After Peter Wilson comment:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\culine}[2]{%
        \newcommand\temp@uline{\bgroup\markoverwith
            {\textcolor{#1}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}%
        \temp@uline{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\cuuline}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uuline{\leavevmode \bgroup
            \UL@setULdepth
            \ifx\UL@on\UL@onin \advance\ULdepth2.8\p@\fi
            \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\lower\ULdepth\hbox
                {\kern-.03em\vbox{\hrule width.2em\kern1\p@\hrule}\kern-.03em}}}%
        \ULon}%
        \temp@uuline{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\cuwave}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uwave{\leavevmode \bgroup
        \ifdim \ULdepth=\maxdimen \ULdepth 3.5\p@
        \else \advance\ULdepth2\p@
        \fi \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\lower\ULdepth\hbox{\sixly \char58}}}\ULon}
        \font\sixly=lasy6 % does not re-load if already loaded, so no memory drain.
        \temp@uwave{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\csout}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@sout{\leavevmode \bgroup
        \ifdim \ULdepth=\maxdimen \ULdepth 3.5\p@
        \else \advance\ULdepth2\p@
        \fi \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\lower\ULdepth\hbox{\sixly \char58}}}\ULon}
        \font\sixly=lasy6 % does not re-load if already loaded, so no memory drain.
        \temp@sout{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\cxout}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uwave{\leavevmode \bgroup
        \ifdim \ULdepth=\maxdimen \ULdepth 3.5\p@
        \else \advance\ULdepth2\p@
        \fi \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\lower\ULdepth\hbox{\sixly \char58}}}\ULon}
        \font\sixly=lasy6 % does not re-load if already loaded, so no memory drain.
        \temp@uwave{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\cdashuline}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uwave{\leavevmode \bgroup
        \ifdim \ULdepth=\maxdimen \ULdepth 3.5\p@
        \else \advance\ULdepth2\p@
        \fi \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\lower\ULdepth\hbox{\sixly \char58}}}\ULon}
        \font\sixly=lasy6 % does not re-load if already loaded, so no memory drain.
        \temp@uwave{#2}%
    }
  \newcommand{\cdotuline}[2]{%
  \UL@protected\def\cdotuline{\leavevmode \bgroup 
    \UL@setULdepth
    \ifx\UL@on\UL@onin \advance\ULdepth2\p@\fi
    \markoverwith{\begingroup
       %\advance\ULdepth0.08ex 
       \lower\ULdepth\hbox{\kern.06em \textcolor{#1}{.}\kern.04em}%
       \endgroup}%
    \ULon}
    }
  \UL@protected\def\greendashuline{\leavevmode \bgroup 
    \UL@setULdepth
    \ifx\UL@on\UL@onin \advance\ULdepth2\p@\fi
    \markoverwith{\kern.13em
    \vtop{\color{green}\kern\ULdepth \hrule width .3em}%
    \kern.13em}\ULon}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\textbf{With Color:}
    \culine{brown}{I am underlined in color.}
%    \culine{red}{\lipsum[1].}

    \cuuline{blue}{I am double underlined in color.}
%    \culine{green}{\lipsum[1].}

    \cuwave{teal}{I am underlined in waves.}
%    \cuwave{blue}{\lorem[1].}

    I am not underlined at all.

    \csout{orange}{I am SOUTED in color}

    \cxout{green}{I am XOUTED in color.}

    \cdashuline{cyan}{I am dash-underlined in color.}

    \cdotuline{red}{I am dot-underlined in color.}

\medskip
\par
\textbf{Without color: (works fine!)}
    \uline{I am underlined in color.}

    \uuline{I am double underlined in color.}

    \uwave{I am underlined in waves.}

    I am not underlined at all.

    \sout{I am SOUTED in color}

    \xout{I am XOUTED in color.}

    \dashuline{I am dash-underlined in color.}

    \dotuline{I am dot-underlined in color.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: use lualatex and the lua-ul package.

Comment: You could also try the `soul` package if you don't use LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Color as parameter is already supported by one of the answers there. Which one is missing exactly?

Comment: Please provide an MWE that we can compile that shows your problem and how you tried to fix it.

Comment: @PeterWilson I edited and added the mwe. Thank you.

Comment: @user202729 only for uline, uuline and uwave.  I´m interested in sout, xout, dash underline and dotted underline, as I posted. Soul package is less beautifull and rich for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you should use the correct original definitions of the macros. If you use the `\uwave` defintion for your `\cxout` macro, of course you will get a the same wavy underline ... =)

Also, you should not use `\newcommand` insinde of your redefinitions, because this will raise an error if you try to use the newly defined macro more than once. Better stick to `\UL@protected\def`.

The only macro you cannot simply edit by inserting some `\color` command is that for `\sout`, but it is quite easy to reuse the definition of the `\uline` macro and shift the line using `\raisebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\culine}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uline{\bgroup\markoverwith
            {\textcolor{#1}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}%
        \temp@uline{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\cuuline}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uuline{\leavevmode \bgroup
            \UL@setULdepth
            \ifx\UL@on\UL@onin \advance\ULdepth2.8\p@\fi
            \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\lower\ULdepth\hbox
                {\kern-.03em\vbox{\hrule width.2em\kern1\p@\hrule}\kern-.03em}}}%
        \ULon}%
        \temp@uuline{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\cuwave}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uwave{\leavevmode \bgroup
        \ifdim \ULdepth=\maxdimen \ULdepth 3.5\p@
        \else \advance\ULdepth2\p@
        \fi \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\lower\ULdepth\hbox{\sixly \char58}}}\ULon}
        \font\sixly=lasy6 % does not re-load if already loaded, so no memory drain.
        \temp@uwave{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\csout}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@sout{\bgroup\markoverwith
            {\textcolor{#1}{\raisebox{1.05ex}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}}\ULon}%
        \temp@sout{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\cxout}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@xout{\leavevmode \bgroup
        \markoverwith{\color{#1}\hbox to.35em{\hss/\hss}}\ULon}%
        \temp@xout{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\cdashuline}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@dashuline{\leavevmode \bgroup 
        \UL@setULdepth
        \ifx\UL@on\UL@onin \advance\ULdepth2\p@\fi
        \markoverwith{\kern.13em
        \vtop{\color{#1}\kern\ULdepth \hrule width .3em}%
        \kern.13em}\ULon}
        \temp@dashuline{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\cdotuline}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@dotuline{\leavevmode \bgroup 
        \UL@setULdepth
        \ifx\UL@on\UL@onin \advance\ULdepth2\p@\fi
        \markoverwith{\begingroup
            %\advance\ULdepth0.08ex 
            \lower\ULdepth\hbox{\kern.06em \textcolor{#1}{.}\kern.04em}%
            \endgroup}%
        \ULon}%
        \temp@dotuline{#2}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textbf{With Color:}

    \culine{brown}{I am underlined in color.}

    \cuuline{blue}{I am double underlined in color.}

    \cuwave{teal}{I am underlined in waves.}

    I am not underlined at all.

    \csout{orange}{I am SOUTED in color}

    \cxout{green}{I am XOUTED in color.}

    \cdashuline{cyan}{I am dash-underlined in color.}

    \cdotuline{red}{I am dot-underlined in color.} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A variant that allows for different thickness:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\cthickuline}[3][0.5pt]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uline{\bgroup\markoverwith
            {\textcolor{#2}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{#1}}}\ULon}%
        \temp@uline{#3}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textbf{With Color:}

    \cthickuline[0.1pt]{red}{I am underlined in color.}

    \cthickuline{red}{I am underlined in color.}

    \cthickuline[1.2pt]{red}{I am underlined in color.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked `\dashuline`. Just corrected this one.

Comment: For me is... Perfect solved. @jasper-habicht Two adds: 1.- I think it could be interesting a new ulem package with your options. Even with thick option. 2.- is possible put |lipsum[1] (with break lines) in a \uwave \uline \uuline?

Comment: @MikaIke As for the `lipsum` problem: see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57652/47927). It seems that you can't use it directly, for reasons that are difficult to grasp for me as well ...