# Need help with package Soul for marking the change of equations

Tags: soul, changes

I am using Soul to mark the change to my manuscript in Overleaf, but it won't work for equations, like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\setstcolor{red} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\st{E = mc^3} E=mc^2  
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

what I want to see is an overstrike on E = mc^3, followed by E = mc^2

Thanks

Comment: Let me guess: they are looking for something to mark *revisions* on a document.

Comment: @Rmano yes, you are right

Comment: @majordoctor: Please update your post with a more direct description of what you want; not just a "I've tried this and it doesn't work" without much context. It'll remove the guesswork from the audience. Can you do that?

Comment: @Werner sorry, I made some changes, please take a look

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please post code, which compiles, once we copied? It‘s not much, that‘s missing, but it‘s annoying to guess where you can easily EDIT … Thank you.

Comment: How many people work on the document?

Comment: @MS-SPO, I post a simple example from my manuscript, and it should be compiled.

Comment: Thank you ... but did you try it? Still important lines are missing, unless you use a quite different Latex environment/editor ... What I expect is code starting with `\documentclass{` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @MS-SPO, I added. I tried, but the error is missing $$ even in equation mode

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ulem` and `xcolor` packages and define a new command as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530454/changing-the-color-of-special-underlines-with-ulem).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\rst{\bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{red}{\rule\[0.6ex\]{10pt}{1pt}}}\ULon}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\rst{Red line through this} but not through this.

\rst{$E=mc^3$} $E=mc^2$

\end{document}
```

Don't forget to wrap your equations in math mode.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what are wrap equations? I am encountering the error:   Missing } inserted.
LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
Missing number, treated as zero.
Missing $ inserted.
Extra }, or forgotten $.
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
Missing $ inserted.

Comment: @majordoctor Your equations should have the math delimiters on either side. So "$E=mc^3$" not "E=mc^3"