# Negative line in Latex

Tags: math-mode

I want to write this [image].
I used $\bar{A$\cup$B}$ but something wrong.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is a *single* formula: `$\overline{A\cup B}$`. If it's part of a bigger formula, start the whole formula with `$` and end it with `$`, with none in between.

Answer (score 1):

Your "formula", viz.,

```
$\bar{A$\cup$B}$
```

contains (at least) three syntax errors:

- the first subformula, `$\bar{A$`, contains an opening curly brace but no closing curly brace;
- the middle subformula, `\cup`, is encountered outside of math-mode; and
- the third subformula, $B}$, contains a closing curly brace but no corresponding opening curly brace.

---

The `\bar` macro places a short horizontal bar across its argument. Hence,  `$\bar{A\cup B}$` results in a single, short bar across the entire formula. This isn't likely to be what you want. `$\bar{A}\cup\bar{B}$` will produce two short horizontal bars -- again, not what you want.

If a single horizontal bar across `A`, `\cup` and `B` is required, you should be writing

```
$\overline{A\cup B}$
```

Some people may find that the line drawn by `\overline` can look too long and, as a result, too "heavy". If you are in this camp, you may find the `\widebar` macro useful. The code for the `\widebar` macro, used in the example code below, is taken straight from [an earlier posting by Hendrik Vogt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/5001).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % required for the following code

%%% The following code was created by Hendrik Vogt; see 
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/5001 for details.
%%% Note that the 'amsmath' package is required.
\makeatletter
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of 
%\macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then 
%no negative kern may follow the bar; an additional {} 
%makes sure that the superscript is high enough in 
%this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
%Enable nesting of accents:
    \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
%If there's more than a single symbol, use the 
%first character instead (see below):
    \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
%Determine the italic correction:
    \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
    \dimen@\wd\tw@
    \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
%Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
    \divide\dimen@ 3
    \@tempdima\wd\tw@
    \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
%Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
    \divide\@tempdima 10
    \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
%Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
%The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
    \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
    \if#31
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
      \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
%Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it 
%is >0 or if a superscript follows:
      \let\final@kern#2%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
      \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
    \else
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
%The following initialises \macc@kerna and 
%calls \mathaccent:
  \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \else
%If the argument consists of more than one symbol, 
%and if the first token is a letter, use that letter 
%for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
      \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
%%% End of Hendrik Vogt's code

\begin{document} 
%$\bar{A$\cup$B}$ %% This throws at least 3 syntax errors

$\bar{A\cup B}$      % much too short

$\bar{A}\cup\bar{B}$ % two separate short bars

$\overline{A\cup B}$ % looks rather "heavy"

$\widebar{A\cup B}$  % better-looking than \overline...
\end{document}
```