# Misplaced alignment tab character & in the first & character. What could be wrong?

Tags: align

```
\begin(align*)
\overline{A \cap B \cap C} &\equiv x \notin A \cap B \cap C & \text{definition of complement} \\
&\equiv \neg x \in A \cap B \cap C &\text{definition of does not belong symbol} \\
&\equiv \neg(x \in A \land x \in B \land x\in C) & \text{definition of intersection} \\
&\equiv \neg(x \in A) \lor \neg (x \in B) \lor \neg (x \in C) & \text{by 1st DeMorgan's Law for logical equiv.} \\
&\equiv x \notin A \lor x \notin B \lor x \notin C & \text{by definition of does not belong symbol} \\
&\equiv x \in \overline{A} \lor x \in \overline{B} \lor x \in \overline{C} &\text{definition of complement} \\
&\equiv x \in (\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \cup \overline{C}) &\text{definition of union}\\
&\equiv \overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \cup \overline{C} &\text{by meaning of set builder notation}
 \end{align*}
```

Comment: A general hint: The required arguments of (undelimited) TeX and LaTeX directives (aka "macros") must be encased in curly braces, *not* round parentheses. This applies to `\begin` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need `\begin{align*}`, not `\begin(align*)`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \overline{A \cap B \cap C}
    &\equiv x \notin A \cap B \cap C                                           && \text{definition of complement} \\
    &\equiv \neg x \in A \cap B \cap C                                         && \text{definition of does not belong symbol} \\
    &\equiv \neg(x \in A \land x \in B \land x\in C)                           && \text{definition of intersection} \\
    &\equiv \neg(x \in A) \lor \neg (x \in B) \lor \neg (x \in C)              && \text{by 1st DeMorgan's Law for logical equiv.} \\
    &\equiv x \notin A \lor x \notin B \lor x \notin C                         && \text{by definition of does not belong symbol} \\
    &\equiv x \in \overline{A} \lor x \in \overline{B} \lor x \in \overline{C} && \text{definition of complement} \\
    &\equiv x \in (\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \cup \overline{C})           && \text{definition of union} \\
    &\equiv \overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \cup \overline{C}                   && \text{by meaning of set builder notation}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I would also left-align rather than right-align the material in the third column.

Comment: @Mico: Good suggestion. Added.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to fixing the obvious syntax error -- it should be `\begin{align*}`, not `\begin(align*)` -- you should probably also avoid mixing expressions for sets with expressions for *members* of a set. In addition, the following answer  uses `\widebar` instead of `\overline` to generate better-proportioned bars  above the letters `A`, `B`, and `C`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.

%% The following definition of '\widebar', for single
%% characters, is from the answer by @wipet at 
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243950, with the
%% PlainTeX code adapted for usage in LaTeX.

\newdimen\tmpdim
\def\widecharS{0.25}
\def\widebar#1{\futurelet\next\widebarA#1\widebarA}
\def\widebarA#1\widebarA{%
   \def\tmp{0}\ifcat\noexpand\next A\def\tmp{1}\fi
   \widebarE
   \ifdim\tmp pt=0pt \overline{#1}%
   \else {\mathpalette\widebarB{#1}}\fi}
\def\widebarB#1#2{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\overline{#2}$}%
   \tmpdim=\tmp\ht0 \advance\tmpdim by-.4pt
   \tmpdim=\widecharS\tmpdim
   \kern\tmpdim\overline{\kern-\tmpdim#2}}
\def\widebarC#1#2 {\ifx#1\end \else 
   \ifx#1\next\def\tmp{#2}\widebarD 
   \else\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\widebarC
   \fi\fi}
\def\widebarD#1\end. {\fi\fi}
\def\widebarE{\widebarC A1.4 J1.2 L.6 O.8 T.5 U.7 V.3 
   W.1 Y.2 a.5 b.2 d1.1 h.5 i.5 k.5 l.3 m.4 n.4 o.6 p.4 
   r.5 t.4 v.7 w.7 x.8 y.8 \alpha1 \beta1 \gamma.6 
   \delta.8 \epsilon.8 \varepsilon.8 \zeta.6 \eta.4
   \theta.8 \vartheta.8 \iota.5 \kappa.8 \lambda.5 
   \mu1 \nu.5 \xi.7 \pi.6 \varpi.9 \rho1 \varrho1 
   \sigma.7 \varsigma.7 \tau.6 \upsilon.7 \phi1
   \varphi.6 \chi.7 \psi1 \omega.5 \cal1 \end. }

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\overline{A \cap B \cap C} 
& \equiv \{\,x\mid x \notin (A \cap B \cap C) \,\}
&&\text{by definition of complement} \\
& \equiv \{\,x\mid \neg x \in (A \cap B \cap C ) \,\}
&&\text{by definition of does not belong symbol} \\
& \equiv \{\,x\mid \neg(x \in A \land x \in B \land x\in C) \,\}
&&\text{by definition of intersection} \\
& \equiv \{\,x\mid \neg(x \in A) \lor \neg (x \in B) \lor \neg (x \in C) \,\}
&&\text{by 1st DeMorgan's Law for logical equiv.} \\
& \equiv \{\,x\mid (x\notin A) \lor (x\notin B) \lor (x\notin C) \,\}
&&\text{by definition of does not belong symbol} \\
& \equiv \{\,x\mid (x \in \widebar{A}) \lor (x \in \widebar{B}) \lor (x \in \widebar{C}) \,\}
&&\text{by definition of complement} \\
& \equiv \{\,x\mid x \in (\widebar{A} \cup \widebar{B} \cup \widebar{C}) \,\}
&&\text{by definition of union}\\
& \equiv \widebar{A} \cup \widebar{B} \cup \widebar{C} 
&&\text{by meaning of set builder notation}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```