# Eliminating extra vertical space inside theorem environment and enumerate

Tags: enumerate, ntheorem

A friend and I are writing an Analysis book. We are using `ntheorem` and many times enumerate inside of various custom theorem style environments. Each time I put enumerate inside any of our theorem environments, I get extra unwanted vertical space between the heading and the beginning of the enumerated list.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[left=1.65cm,right=1.65cm,top=2.45cm,bottom=2.60cm] 
{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,amsbsy,mathabx,array,color}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,framed,latexsym,multicol,pstricks,slashed,xcolor,multicol}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[amsmath,framed,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoreminframepreskip{0pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{0pt}
\theoremframepreskip{1cm}
\theoremframepostskip{1cm}
\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
    \psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{them}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

  \begin{them}
  Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Then:
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item If $X$ and $Y$ are finite disjoint sets, then $X \bigcup$ is finite and $\overline{\overline{X \bigcup Y}} = \overline{\overline{X}} + \overline{\overline{Y}}$.
      \item If $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets, then $X \bigcup Y$ is finite and $\overline{\overline{X \bigcup Y}} = \overline{\overline{X}} + \overline{\overline{Y}} \setminus (\overline{\overline{X \bigcap Y}})$.
      \item If $X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are finite sets, then 
$\displaystyle{\bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i}$ is finite.   
    \end{enumerate}
\end{them}

\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the [package documentation of the **enumitem** package](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).The vertical spacing of enumerate environments is explained here: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300512/118714](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300512/118714) .  As you have loaded the **enumitem** package, you can use keyval-syntax for adjusting: `\begin{enumerate}[topsep=...]`

Comment: You should type `X\cup Y`, not `X\bigcup Y` and, similarly, `X\cap Y`. The final formula should be `$\bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i$`, without `\displaystyle` that spoils the interline spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution  with `enumitem`. I took the opportunity to improve a bit your theorem layout, mainly making a blurred shadow, and upshpae enumerate numbers. Also, I borrowed a code  from the answer  to [double-bar-overline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412815/double-bar-overline) to defined small package defining a `\widedblbar` command, that fits better italic letters. I removed package `mathabx`, as it also defines a `\widebar` command, and anyway, it overwrites mathematical symbols.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.65cm, top=2.45cm, bottom=2.60cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsbsy, array,color}%mathabx,
\usepackage{widedblbar}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, framed, latexsym, multicol,slashed, xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-blur}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[amsmath, framed, thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoreminframepreskip{0pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{0pt}
\theoremframepreskip{1cm}
\theoremframepostskip{1cm}
\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
    \psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,linecolor=black, blur=true]}
\newshadedtheorem{them}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

  \begin{them}
  Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Then:
    \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, font=\upshape, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt]
      \item If $X$ and $Y$ are finite disjoint sets, then $X \bigcup Y$ is finite and $\widedblbar{X \bigcup Y} = \widedblbar{X} + \widedblbar{Y}$.
      \item If $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets, then $X \bigcup Y$ is finite and $\widedblbar{X \bigcup Y} = \widedblbar{X} + \widedblbar{Y} \setminus (\widedblbar{X \bigcap Y})$.
      \item If $X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are finite sets, then
    $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i $ is finite.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{them}

\end{document}
```

Code  in the small  package:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% This code is a slight modification of Hendrik Vogt's \widebar %%
%% See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337 %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% IDENTIFICATION
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{widedblbar}

\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\wideaccent[2]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@accent{#1}{#2}{0}}}{\wide@accent{#1}{#2}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@accent[3]{\if@single{#2}{\wide@accent@{#1}{#2}{#3}{1}}{\wide@accent@{#1}{#2}{#3}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@accent@[4]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
%Enable nesting of accents:
    \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
%If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
    \if#42 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
%Determine the italic correction:
    \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
    \dimen@\wd\tw@
    \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
%Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
    \divide\dimen@ 3
    \@tempdima\wd\tw@
    \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
%Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
    \divide\@tempdima 10
    \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
%Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
%The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
    \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
    \if#41
      #1{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
      \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
%Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
      \let\final@kern#3%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
      \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
    \else
      #1{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#2}%
    \fi
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
%The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
  \if#41
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#2}%
  \else
%If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
%a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#2\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
      \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\widebar{\wideaccent\overline}
\newcommand\widedblbar{\wideaccent\doubleoverline}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]