# How to put bar on top of fields

Tags: math-mode, accents

I'd like to know how to but bars (like for example `$\bar s$`) directly above the letter of the field, for example above this `$\mathbb{F}_p$`,

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$` or `$\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$`

Comment: I assume the bar in `$\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$` looks too puny? There is also `$\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$` and many other ways: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16337/35864

Comment: as before you should never omit the `{}` even though it sometimes works to do so, if you always used braces `\bar{s}` and `\mathbb{F}_{p}` then `\bar{\mathbb{F}}_{p}` or `\bar{\mathbb{F}_{p}}` would work naturally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three such combining accents [in Unicode](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf), which are available in [`unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf#nameddest=6) as `\bar`, `\overbar` and `\overline`.

Some of these accents will combine into a single bar if you put them over consecutive symbols, and you probably do not want that.  (If you do, you want to put a single `\overline` on both, since the two symbols might have slightly-different heights.)  I’ve illustrated the examples with two consecutive bar accents.

I defined a new `\widebar` that adds some spacing in between (as a log-like operator).  This is wider than the `\widebar` in the other examples.  The conventional name for a non-extensible version of `\overline` was `\closure`, but that’s already defined to mean something else.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareRobustCommand\widebar[1]{\mathop{\overline{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\( \bar{\mathbb{A}}\bar{\mathbb{F}}^{*}_{p^k} \)

\( \overbar{\mathbb{A}}\overbar{\mathbb{F}}^{*}_{p^k} \)

\( \overline{\mathbb{A}}\overline{\mathbb{F}}^{*}_{p^k} \)

\( \widebar{\mathbb{A}}\widebar{\mathbb{F}}^{*}_{p^k} \)

\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Math sample]

In the default font (Latin Modern Math), you will notice that `\bar` is very similar to `\overbar`.  This is not true in many other fonts.  For example, here is the same sample set in the font Stix Two Math:

[image: Stix Two Sample]

Much of this code (but not `\overbar`) will still work without `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the same `\mathbb{F}^*_{p^k}` from your previous question:

> [image]

There are three bars I know of: `\bar`, `\overline`, and [`\widebar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/134574). Personally, I like the appearance of the `\widebar`, but it changes the height of the `*`. Your choice :)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{widebar}% From here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/134574

\begin{document}

\(\mathbb{\bar{F}}^{*}_{p^k}\)

\(\mathbb{\overline{F}}^{*}_{p^k}\)

\(\mathbb{\widebar{F}}^{*}_{p^k}\)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

As `\bar` looks petty with capital letters, I propose  two variants: one based on `\overline`, and another one gives a code to use the extensible `\widebar` command from `mathabx` without loading the package. Compare:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<5><6><7><8><9><10>
<10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>
mathx10
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\bar{\mathbb{F}}^{*}_{p^{k}} \\
 \widebar{\mathbb{F}}^{*}_{p^{k}} \\
 \mkern 0.54mu\overline{\mkern-0.4mu\mathbb{F}\mkern-0.4mu}\mkern0.5mu\vphantom{\mathbb{F}}^{*}_{p^{k}} 
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]