# Adjust spacing between preceded superscript and base

Tags: math-mode, spacing, superscripts

Depending on the letter in the base there is space to the preceded superscript. Letters like T, W, Y use ink in the top left corner, so there is no space, but when using I, D, E, ... (these letters don't have a component in their top left corner) there is space in front of them.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
$T^b$ %no space

${}^b T$ ${}^b W$ ${}^b Y$ %no space

$I^b$ %no space

${}^b I$ ${}^b D$ ${}^b E$ %spacing between b and I, D or E

$\tensor[^b]I{}$ %doesn't help
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which is based on (the second half of) [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/156366) amazing answer by Hendrik Vogt. It works by hacking into `amsmath`'s accent placement mechanism.
I do not fully understand it.

I've defined `\presup{<superscript>}{<letter>}`, which does what you ask, and applied it to all of the letters you mention.
I've additionally applied it to the letters "A" and "J" (which I think are the worst offenders) and to `\mathcal{A}`.
Apart from the "T" (which now looks worse), I think these are all improvements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in command names
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
\newcommand*\presup[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
    {}^{#1}\rel@kern{-0.8}\macc@nucleus
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
  \macc@nested@a\relax111{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother  %% <- revert @

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lccccccccc}
    Bad: & ${}^xA^x$ & ${}^xJ^x$ & ${}^xT^x$ & ${}^xW^x$ & ${}^xY^x$ & ${}^xI^x$ & ${}^xD^x$ & ${}^xE^x$ & ${}^x\mathcal{A}^x$
    \\
    Good: & $\presup{x}{A}^x$ & $\presup{x}{J}^x$ & $\presup{x}{T}^x$ & $\presup{x}{W}^x$ & $\presup{x}{Y}^x$ & $\presup{x}{I}^x$ & $\presup{x}{D}^x$ & $\presup{x}{E}^x$ & $\presup{x}{\mathcal{A}}^x$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]