# Long bar over an ordered pair

Tags: typography, displaystyle, bar

I'd like to typeset a long bar symbol over an ordered pair like `(g,\epsilon)`. The best I could do so far is naif and really poor:

[image]

Is there a standard command for that?

Comment: `\overline` is an option.

Answer (score 7):

Here there is a possible MWE code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\overline{(g,\epsilon)}$ or $(\overline{g,\epsilon})$
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I propose either to use @Hendrik Vogt's solution, as an answer to a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package) of mine, or to use the `\widebar` command, from `mathabx`, without loading the package. Here is a demo of both solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter % Hendrik Vogt's code
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
%Enable nesting of accents:
    \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
%If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
    \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
%Determine the italic correction:
    \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
    \dimen@\wd\tw@
    \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
%Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
    \divide\dimen@ 3
    \@tempdima\wd\tw@
    \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
%Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
    \divide\@tempdima 10
    \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
%Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
%The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
    \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
    \if#31
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
      \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
%Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
      \let\final@kern#2%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
      \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
    \else
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
%The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
  \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \else
%If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
%a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
      \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

%%%% with mathabx (without loading it))

    \DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
    <-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
    <8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
    <10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
    }{}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
    \DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
    \DeclareMathAccent{\varwidebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

\[ \widebar{(g, \varepsilon)} \]
\[ \varwidebar{(g, \varepsilon)} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]