# A universal method for left-hand alignment of a sequence of equalities

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, align, best-practices, brackets

With this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, mathrsfs}

%% Code for '\widebar' macro is courtesy of
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253
\makeatletter
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
%Enable nesting of accents:
    \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
%If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
    \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
%Determine the italic correction:
    \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
    \dimen@\wd\tw@
    \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
%Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
    \divide\dimen@ 3
    \@tempdima\wd\tw@
    \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
%Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
    \divide\@tempdima 10
    \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
%Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
%The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
    \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
    \if#31
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
      \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
%Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
      \let\final@kern#2%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
      \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
    \else
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
%The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
  \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \else
%If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
%a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
      \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
%% End of code block for \widebar macro


\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
\mathscr F(\bar{r}(t))&=& \int_a^{b} L dt& =&\int_a^{b} \left[L \frac{dt}{d\tau}\right]d\tau=\\
=\int_a^{b} \Bigl[-mc^2-q\varphi\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}}+q\frac{\bar{u}\cdot \widebar{A}}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}}\Bigr]  d\tau=& &&&\\
=\int_a^{b} \left[-mc^2+q\,\boldsymbol{\mathcal{U}}\cdot \boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}\right] d\tau&&&&\\
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

I have this output:

[image]

However, I would like to have the following alignment as the image below:

[image]

In the last few days I have done several tests but I have not succeeded. For other formulas the alignment on the left is very good. With this formula I can't do it.

Lastly, how can I improve the shape of the integral of the second line where the two green rectangles are highlighted? The square brackets do not respect the length of the integral symbol.

Comment: It is not `eqnarray`. Use a single `&` per line, before the first `=`.

Comment: @egreg Kindest Prof. I ask you a kindness; please can you give me a complete answer with the directions that I have given? I hope that the translation from Italian into English with DeepL is clear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it normal practice where you come from to have an = sign at the end of one line *and* the start of the next? because it definitely isn't here, you shouldn't have one at the end of the line

Comment: @Au101 - Placing an `=` symbol both at the end of one line and at the start on the next line of a multiline equation is a common convention in some national typographic systems.

Comment: I've take the liberty of adding a note to your code to mention that the `\widebar` macro comes from  [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253) to the query [Can I get a \widebar without using the mathabx package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16337)

Comment: In my opinion, in your example, the equal sign at the end of the line is useless. Only those written in columns are required.

Comment: @AndréC - Whether or not the `=` at the ends of lines 1 and 2 are "useless" is immaterial if they are there because the OP must conform to an Italian typographic convention.

Comment: @Mico This is a strange convention since the equal sign is no longer seen as a relationship of equivalence.

Comment: @Mico I see! You learn something new every day :)

Comment: No downvotes so far -- what's going on?! :-)

Comment: @Mico Never Say Never is an old Sean Connery movie of 007. :-) Anything can happen. :-)

Comment: @Mico Why should there be down votes?

Comment: @AndréC Because there are frequent times of the year that haters attack me.

Comment: @Sebastiano Why are they doing this?

Comment: @AndréC - They just downvote, no explanations given, *ever*. And they really seem to like downvoting Sebastiano's queries. Who knows what motivates them? Maybe they dislike [Saint Sebastian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Sebastian) and believe it's appropriate to downvote queries by persons whose first name happens to be Sebastian[o]? At this point, any guess is as good, or bad, as any other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My mathematician's eyes bleed when I see something like

```
\frac{<whatever}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}
```

appearing more than once; I guess in your document it appears *many* times.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, mathrsfs,bm}

\makeatletter
%<...long code omitted for brevity...>
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
\mathscr F(\bar{r}(t))
&= \int_a^{b} L dt = \int_a^{b} \left[L \frac{dt}{d\tau}\right]\,d\tau=\\
&=\int_a^{b} [-mc^2-q\varphi\gamma(u)+q\bar{u}\cdot \widebar{A}\gamma(u)] \,d\tau=\\
&=\int_a^{b} [-mc^2+q\,\bm{\mathcal{U}}\cdot \bm{\mathcal{A}}] \,d\tau\\
\end{aligned}
\]
where
\[
\gamma(u)=\left(1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2}
\]
\end{document}
```

There should be a *single* `&` per line.

I also fixed the usage of `\left` and `\right` and loaded `bm` that performs better than `amsbsy` and its `\boldsymbol` command, replaced by `\bm` (but `\boldsymbol` works as well).

[image]

Comment: What makes your mathematician's eyes bleed when you see this `\frac{<whatever}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}`?

Comment: @egreg Thank you so much for your patience and courtesy.

Comment: @AndréC I think his eyes bleed because of the use of `dfrac`: it should (*always*) be `frac`. Even in this case the OP can use `u^2/c^2` since it means the same but more compact.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some suggestions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,mathrsfs,bm,bigints}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{aligned}
    \mathscr{F}(\bar{r}(t)) &= \int_a^b L \,\mathrm{d}t = \int_a^b \left[L \dfrac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau} \right] \,\mathrm{d}\tau = \\
      &= \bigint_a^b \left[ -m c^2 - q \varphi \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}} + 
        q \frac{\bar{u} \cdot \bar{A}}{\sqrt{1 - \dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}} \right] \,\mathrm{d}\tau = \\
      &= \int_a^b \bigl[ -m c^2 + q\,\bm{\mathcal{U}} \cdot \bm{\mathcal{A}} \bigr] \mathrm{d}\tau
  \end{aligned}
\]

\begin{align*}
  \mathscr{F}(\bar{r}(t)) &= \int_a^b L \,\mathrm{d}t = \int_a^b \left[L \dfrac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau} \right] \,\mathrm{d}\tau = \\
    &= \int_a^b \bigl( -m c^2 - q \varphi / \sqrt{1 - u^2 / c^2} + 
      q (\bar{u} \cdot \bar{A}) / \sqrt{1 - u^2 / c^2} \,\bigr) \,\mathrm{d}\tau = \\
    &= \int_a^b \bigl( -m c^2 + q\,\bm{\mathcal{U}} \cdot \bm{\mathcal{A}} \bigr) \,\mathrm{d}\tau
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The first suggestion uses an extended integral from [`bigints`](//ctan.org/pkg/bigints), but it places far too big an emphasis visually. Hence the second suggestion, and to use a less-intrusive fraction of the form a / b.

Comment: No, please, no! ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much. See the comment to Mico's answer.

Answer (score 2):

First you had unnecessary ampersands, and others were missing.

To have some  equations left aligned, the simplest way is to use the `fleqn`  environment from `nccmath`. Further, I improved the layout of the middle row, using the `\mfrac` command (`medium-sized` fractions) instead of `\dfrac`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, mathrsfs, nccmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
%Enable nesting of accents:
    \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
%If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
    \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
%Determine the italic correction:
    \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
    \dimen@\wd\tw@
    \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
%Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
    \divide\dimen@ 3
    \@tempdima\wd\tw@
    \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
%Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
    \divide\@tempdima 10
    \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
%Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
%The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
    \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
    \if#31
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
      \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
%Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
      \let\final@kern#2%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
      \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
    \else
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
%The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
  \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \else
%If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
%a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
      \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
\mathscr F(\bar{r}(t))&= \int_a^{b} L dt =\int_a^{b} \left[L \frac{dt}{d\tau}\right]d\tau=\\
 & =\int_a^{b} \Bigl[-mc^2-q\varphi\mfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\mfrac{u^{2}\mathstrut}{c^{2}}}}+q\mfrac{\bar{u}\cdot \widebar{A}}{\sqrt{1-\mfrac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}}\Bigr] d\tau=& &&&\\
 & =\int_a^{b} \left[-mc^2+q\,\boldsymbol{\mathcal{U}}\cdot \boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}\right] d\tau\\
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. See the comment to Mico's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late to the game, but hopefully still useful.

[image]

In addition to placing `&` alignment points where they're needed, the main change from your sample code is the use of inline-fraction notation for the denominator terms in the middle row. By the way, there is no need for `\\` at the end of the final row of an `aligned` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, mathrsfs, bm}

%% Code for '\widebar' macro is from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/5001
\makeatletter
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of 
%\macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no 
%negative kern may follow the bar; an additional {} 
%makes sure that the superscript is high enough in 
%this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
%Enable nesting of accents:
    \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
%If there's more than a single symbol, use the first 
%character instead (see below):
    \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
%Determine the italic correction:
    \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
    \dimen@\wd\tw@
    \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
%Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
    \divide\dimen@ 3
    \@tempdima\wd\tw@
    \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
%Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
    \divide\@tempdima 10
    \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
%Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
%The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
    \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
    \if#31
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
      \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
%Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
      \let\final@kern#2%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
      \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
    \else
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
%The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
  \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \else
%If the argument consists of more than one symbol, 
%and if the first token is a letter, use that letter 
%for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
      \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
\mathscr{F} (\bar{r}(t))
&=\int_a^{b} \! L \,dt 
 = \int_a^{b} \Bigl[L \frac{dt}{d\tau}\Bigr] d\tau = \\
&=\int_a^{b} \biggl[-mc^2-q\varphi\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}
+q\frac{\bar{u}\cdot \widebar{A}}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}\biggr]  d\tau = \\
&=\int_a^{b} [-mc^2+q\,\bm{\mathcal{U}}\cdot \bm{\mathcal{A}}\,]\, d\tau
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I need everything to learn and to recognize the differences and tricks of the trade :-). The questions were all voted (as always) positively.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I've modified the code, using `\mfrac` for all fractions in the middle row (I think it looks nicer).

Comment: @Bernard I hope that the electronic translation is good: you like everyone else is as if you were at home when you write to me. Obviously the polite and sensitive ones.