# How can I write this bar in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, bar

I want to write this in LaTeX:

[image: Ori]

However, `$$\overline{S_n}^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - M_n)^2$$` gives me:

[image: Ove]

whereas `$$\bar{S_n}^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - M_n)^2$$` gives me:

[image: Bar]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Put the subscript outside the `\overline`: `\overline{S}_n^2`. BTW, use `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`. However, my personal preference would be `\bar{S}_n^2` (definitely not `\bar{S_n}^2` with the subscript inside).

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package/60253#60253

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hope the below code may helps you...

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\[
\overline{S}^{2}_{n}
\]

\[
\overline{S_{n}}^{2}
\]

\[
\bar{S_{n}}^{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Using Hendrik Vogt's code in his answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package/60253#60253), you have a `\widebar` command which takes into account  the italic angle of the glyph:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
    \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\makeatletter
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\DeclareRobustCommand\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
%Enable nesting of accents:
    \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
%If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
    \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
%Determine the italic correction:
    \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
    \dimen@\wd\tw@
    \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
%Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
    \divide\dimen@ 3
    \@tempdima\wd\tw@
    \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
%Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
    \divide\@tempdima 10
    \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
%Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
%The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
    \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
    \if#31
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
      \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
%Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
      \let\final@kern#2%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
      \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
    \else
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
%The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
  \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \else
%If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
%a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
      \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \[ \widebar{S}_n^2 = \mfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i} - M_{n})^{2} \]%

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would say

```
  \documentclass[]{article}

  \begin{document}

  $$\overline{S}_n^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - M_n)^2$$

  \end{document}
```