# \bar y polinomios

Tags: math-mode

Is it possible in Latex to get this expession ?.

[image]

I have tried like this

```
$\bar {\exists  Z }= \bar {\left \{ x_1x_2: \exists ix_i = 0 \right \}}  $
```

and only shows the bar over the exists symbol.

Comment: Welcome! Use `\overline` instead of `\bar`.

Comment: Just in addition to the cats comment: `\bar` is an accent, a part of a font and thus cannot grow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `\overline` instead of `\bar`. While the length of the bar displayed with `\bar` is fixed, the length of the bar displayed with `\overline` varies according to its argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\( \overline{\{ x_1 x_2 : \exists i \ x_i = 0\}} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, there's no need to use `\left` and `\right` here since the curly brackets will not get any bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be using `\widebar` with a macro of @Hendrik Vogt [Can I get a \widebar without using the mathabx package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package/60253#60253). Here there is the result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\makeatletter % using \widebar macro Hendrik Vogt: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package/60253#60253
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
    \rel@kern{0.8}%
    \overline{\rel@kern{-0.8}\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.2}}%
    \rel@kern{-0.2}%
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
  \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[\widebar{\Set{x_1 x_2 \colon \exists i \, x_i = 0}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\Set` command is used with `braket` package to give a just blank spaces to the left and to the right.