# Improving the output of \overline when using LuaLaTeX with unicode-math

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

Consider the following example, to be compiled with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\( f \overline{f} f \)

\( i \overline{i} i \)

\( j \overline{j} j \)

\( l \overline{l} l \)

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

As you can see, the placement of `\overline` is not very appropriate for these letters (but for other letters or longer things `\overline` seems fine). Is there some LuaTeX magic that can somehow improve this behavior?

Comment: @mickep Thank you for mentioning this. This behavior is actually introduced by the second font, I shall simplify my MWE.

Comment: There are two problems here: (1) the wrong kerning LuaTeX applies; (2) `\overline` should be `\bar`.

Comment: @egreg I defined a command for complex conjugation to use `\overline`, `\bar` would be too short if the content is not a single letter.

Comment: You should look into the posting [Can I get a \widebar without using the mathabx package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16337/5001) and especially [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/5001) for the definition of a macro called `\widebar`, which is to `\bar` as `\widetilde` is to `\tilde`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for this. But since this command is based on `\overline`, the result is still not good under LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Jinwen `\wideoverbar` is your friend.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for this. Two problems: 1) `f \wideoverbar{f}` and `\wideoverbar{f} f` has different whitespace between the two letters, 2) is it safe to redefine `\overline` to be `\wideoverbar`? Though `\wideoverbar` is not perfect, it certainly looks a lot better than `\overline` under LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't like at all the standard way of LuaTeX that suppresses italic correction in math formulas. Anyway, `\overline` is not the answer you're looking for. Use `\wideoverbar`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\mathitalicsmode=1

\begin{document}

\( f \overline{f} f \)

\( i \overline{i} i \)

\( j \overline{j} j \)

\( l \overline{l} l \)

\( f \bar{f} ff \) \(f\overbar{f}ff\) \(f\wideoverbar{f}ff\)

\( i \bar{i} ii \)

\( j \bar{j} jj \)

\( l \bar{l} ll \)

Now a serious formula \(\wideoverbar{a+b}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output when removing `\mathitalicsmode=1`

[image]

No, thanks!