# Code to give a "nice" xbar works fine but fails if in a section heading

Tags: accents, math-fonts

I was searching for a better xbar and found an answer here from about 11 years ago:

[Can I get a \widebar without using the mathabx package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package)

I used the abbreviated code and it works fine. However, when I put it in a section heading I get a compiler error. Here is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%%%%%%%%%%%% Code to make a nicer xbar %%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
\newcommand*\Xbar[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
    \rel@kern{0.8}%
    \overline{\rel@kern{-0.8}\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.2}}%
    \rel@kern{-0.2}%
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
  \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End of Code %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
$\Xbar{X}$
\section{All about $\Xbar{X}$}
\end{document}
```

The first instance is fine but the one in \section blows up. This is way beyond my skill level -- I've no idea what the code between \makeatletter and \makeatother does so I can't even begin to think about debugging. I don't even know what tags to use for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\protect` before `\Xbar{X}`, such as `\section{All about $\protect\Xbar{X}$}`.

Or use `\NewDocumentCommand{\Xbar}{m}{` instead of `\newcommand*\Xbar[1]{`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Clara. The first option (protect) didn't work for me but the second did. I'm back in business.