# Prettier \overline and \bar

Tags: bar, overline

This has bothered me for a long time but I really dislike the way `\overline` looks. It always looks too clunky and far away from the letter or number it's over, or sometimes too close. Similarly, `\bar` is too short for most of the times I would need it. Are there any packages or hacks to get nicer looking overbars?  Ideally it would adapt more based on the character I used it on. Thank you all!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16337/35864 might be interesting.

Comment: @moewe  yes, that helps a ton, thank you.

Comment: @SebGlav yes, that helps a ton, thank you