# Symbol for logical equivelence

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm trying to use this symbol in a LaTeX document I'm writing but I can't for the life of me, find how to write it in LaTeX:

[image]

The symbol means that two expressions are logicically equivalent (i.e. A |==| B)Can anybody identify the missing symbol?

Comment: I am not sure which symbol you look for, but did you try detexify: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: From `mathabx` package you can do a trick `$\vDash\!\!\Dashv $`

Comment: The standard symbol for logical equivalence is “⇔”. Are you sure you are looking for a different symbol (apparently, one that has not even been coded as a character in Unicode)?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela -- this symbol *is* in unicode -- U+29E6, "gleich stark = tautological equivalent".  see also the question [Does the mirror image of the \models symbol exist in TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94963/579).  also note that, since the symbol is in unicode, it should be found in the `stix` or `xits` fonts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the use of packages, you could do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\logequiv{\mathrel{\vert\mkern-3mu{=}\mkern-3mu{=}\mkern-3mu\vert}}
\begin{document}
$ A \logequiv B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you didn't like the height of the `\vert`s, you could do this instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\logequiv{\mathrel{%
  \rule{.3pt}{1.3ex}\mkern-1mu{=}\mkern-8mu{=}\mkern-2mu\rule{.3pt}{1.3ex}}}
\begin{document}
$ A \logequiv B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Could you explain us why `-3mu`? Is the length of some symbol?

Comment: @Sigur The `\mkern` with a negative argument removes the natural space between the two symbols.  The `mu` is the unit of mathematical kerning.  I just played with the actual numbers until I ate up all the space.  My experience is that symbols have a natural space around them in integer units of `mu`, though I could be wrong.

Comment: @Sigur I should add that, in both math and text kerning, the kern has no glue, and will therefore not stretch or shrink depending on the line length, unlike (for example) `\hspace`.  Therefore, the (m)kern is the proper way to combine symbols together.

Comment: I think this might be flawed; what happens when the text size of the document isn't the default size but is changed to say 14pt? Wouldn't the spacing change?

Comment: @ToddDavies It is true that the solution is tailored to a particular font size.  Different versions could be developed for different font sizes, which would be the easiest.  With more calculation, a self-adjusting version could be developed, as well, I'm sure.

Answer (score 5):

There is actually a dedicated package for typesetting symbols of this sort. They are called turnstiles and the package is called `turnstile`. It is included in TeX Live and can typeset turnstiles of essentially any kind. It is actually a big improvement on what was available before which was essentially just mathematics symbols. For very simple turnstiles, I sometimes find the maths symbols look better but it really depends what you need and what the context is (e.g. where you are pulling your connective symbols from etc.) In any case, for more complex turnstiles such as this one, it is definitely the best option I'm aware of:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{turnstile}
\newcommand*{\myequiv}{\sdststile{}{}}

\begin{document}

The symbol you need:
\[
  \myequiv
\]

A selection of other possibilities:
\[
    \sststile{T}{}\quad \sdtstile{a^+}{}\quad \dtdtstile{A}{B}\quad \nsttstile{}{C}
\]

\end{document}
```

produces (probably - I can't check):

[image: selected turnstiles]

Note that the sample image posted in the question seems to have a slight gap on the right. I'm pretty sure that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find that symbol (I believe that there is one) as a unique character you can combine two others to obtain a very similar one.

From `mathabx` package you can define

```
\newcommand{\myequiv}{\vDash\!\!\Dashv}
```

to use as `$A\myequiv B$`.

[image]

Comment: but beware that the `mathabx` fonts change a lot of other symbols as well.  there are several questions that address how to access just a few symbols from a font rather than loading the whole thing via a package.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, well pointed.

Comment: To extract just a particular symbol from `mathabx` you could follow an approach such as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113437/stealth-arrow-in-math/113472#113472 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font.

Comment: If you didn't want to use `mathabx`, you could first define `\Dashv` by `\newcommand{\Dashv}{\mathrel{\scalebox{-1}[1]{$\vDash$}}}` (using package `graphicx`).