# MinionPro conflicting with amssymb

Tags: incompatibility, minionpro, amssymb

I am using the package `MinionPro`. But I need some symbols, for example, `\gnapprox` and `\mho`, available on the package `amssymb`.

Well, here is my code (as minimal as possible):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\gnapprox \]

\[\mho \]
\end{document}
```

But I got the errors:

```
Command `\mathfrak' already defined. \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{euf}{m}{n}
Command `\mathfrak' not defined as a math alphabet. ...athAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{euf}{b}{n}
Command `\centerdot' already defined. ...ymbol{\centerdot} {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"05}
Command `\veebar' already defined. ...mbol{\veebar} {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"59}
Command `\barwedge' already defined. ...mbol{\barwedge} {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"5A}
Command `\doublebarwedge' already defined. ...ol{\doublebarwedge} {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"5B}
Command `\circledS' already defined. ...mbol{\circledS} {\mathord}{AMSa}{"73}
Command `\dotplus' already defined. ...mbol{\dotplus} {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"75}
Command `\complement' already defined. ...mbol{\complement} {\mathord}{AMSa}{"7B}
Command `\divideontimes' already defined. ...ol{\divideontimes} {\mathbin}{AMSb}{"3E}
Command `\thicksim' already defined. ...ol{\thicksim} {\mathrel}{AMSb}{"73}
Command `\thickapprox' already defined. ...ol{\thickapprox} {\mathrel}{AMSb}{"74}
Command `\hslash' already defined. ...ol{\hslash} {\mathord}{AMSb}{"7D}
```

How is the right way to use both packages?

Comment: take a look at the answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9956/) to see how to include just a few symbols from a font.  the symbols `\gnapprox` and `\mho` are in the `msbm10` font.  you can `texdoc amsfonts` and look in appendix e (p.37) for their location in the font, or set your own font chart using the technique in the answer already mentioned.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, great! I'm editing that solution to my case but I don't know what to do with the command `\hyphenchar\font45`. Should I change something? Should I look at the font table to some particular glyph?

Comment: you can simply ignore the `\hyphenchar\font45` and leave an empty group `{}` in its place.  `\hyphenchar` is really needed only for text fonts.  the relevant command for `msbm` is in the file `umsb.fd`: `\DeclareFontFamily{U}{msb}{}`

Comment: OK, it works! The problem is that the symbol is too big compared with the normal `\approx` for example. Probably I'm missing something related to the font sizes.

Comment: i don't have access to minion pro, so i can't really investigate this.  but instead of `msbm10` you might try `msbm9`, making a wild guess that minion symbols really are generally smaller than computer modern (which is what `msbm` is based on).

Comment: Note also that `MnSymbol`, desgined to work with Minion, has some of the symbols, e.g., `\gnapprox`. However, it seems that there is no `\mho`.

Comment: @Sigur If you have solved your problem, can you add a self-answer? Or better point out what's still amiss.

Comment: @Sigur I notice your comment here suggests you solved the issue: could you post some form of answer?

Comment: @JosephWright, to be true, I'm not able to post a good answer since it is not so simple. But I'd liked this solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9959

Answer (score 3):

`gnapprox` is also available in `MnSymbol`, though slighly different from the amssymb version. Here is a variant so that the `mho`symbol lies on the baseline:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\def\mho{\raisebox{0.96\depth}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$ \Omega $}} }


\begin{document}

\[ \gnapprox\rlap{\rule[-0.1pt]{1cm}{0.1pt}}{\mho\enspace \Omega
```

} ]

```
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Given that all other characters with rounded features at the baseline are allowed some undershoot (i.e., their lower "edges" are allowed to intersect the baseline ever so slightly), I would have said it's OK to give some undershoot to `\mho` as well. However, there's no arguing about taste, right?

Comment: The problem is that without adjustment, the mho symbol does not intersect the base line: it's slightly `above` it. Don't you think it's more problematic? What's funny is the same trick with Computer Modern requires no adjustment.

Comment: OK, not having the fonts that go with the MinionPro package, I wasn't aware of the problem with the unadjusted `\mho` symbol. I'd guess that a very slight undershoot -- mimicking the extent of the undershoot in the letter `O` -- would be best.

Comment: Yes. In my proposed code, one could change `0.96\depth` to `0.95\depth`.

Comment: But I can't use XeLaTeX with the above. At least in this system, a similar problem to tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16801/ ensued

Comment: You can use XeLaTeX only for text and let the MinionPro package take care of maths. It  suffices to load fontspec with option `no-math` and MinionPro with option `onlymath`.

Comment: back to `fontspec`? unbelievable. No Bernard. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid I misunderstood your previous comment. Why did you mention XeLaTeX then?

Comment: Bernard. Because it is usually xeLaTeX my default engine in my editor. If I were to compile the above with XeLaTeX, then it is XeLaTeX fault, for lack of better error management. Anyhow, `job aborted`

Comment: Bernard. I'll add the error of your code, in my own answer. And please, don't take it the wrong way. My intention is not to discredit your answer, but to figure out a better solution between `MinionPro` and the use of `\mho`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16830/discussion-between-bernard-and-doed).