# Import empty set from Computer Modern font

Tags: symbols

I use `\mathabx` package because I like much more their mathematical symbols. Except for the empty set symbol (`$\emptyset$` in `LaTeX`). I would like to changed it by the standard Computer Modern symbol. But I don't know how to do it. There are some examples to import particular symbols, but I don't undertsand them.

For example, the code

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\abxcup}{\mathbin}{matha}{'131}
```

has been taken from the question [The standard \cup vs. the mathabx \cup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9956/the-standard-cup-vs-the-mathabx-cup). Question [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) also has a similar code. How can I changed them to get the standard empty set symbol?

Thanks

Comment: Is`\varnothing` (`amssymb` package) what you're looking for?

Comment: @FranckPastor No, it is `\emptyset` from `amssymb`. Maybe I should add it in the question.

Comment: `\emptyset` doesn't come from the `amssymb` fonts, but from the standard Computer Modern math fonts. Its variant from the `amssymb` fonts is precisely `\varnothing`.

Comment: I thought that but yout comment confused me.

Comment: Personally it's your question I find confusing in its current form ;-). So if I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to use the `\varnothing` symbol without having to load the whole `amssymb` package?

Comment: No no. My question doesn't say anything about `\varnothing`. The usual `\emptyset`symbol. The ''slashed 0''.

Comment: @FranckPastor [Number 4](https://www.google.es/search?client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&biw=1366&bih=628&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=CAtZWoGBI8SzUd6zgqgI&q=emptyset+math&oq=emptyset+math&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i19k1l3.1867.2434.0.2656.5.5.0.0.0.0.171.483.1j3.4.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..1.2.204...0i30i19k1.0.3_inT8MdFCk#imgrc=om3CUlnQo82bIM:)

Comment: @Dog_69: The  correct mathematical symbol is precisely mathabx `\emptyset` or amssymb `\varnothing`. Computer Modern  `\emptyset` is a notation borrowed from Computer Science. See for instance any book of Bourbaki.

Comment: @Bernard Really? I can't belive you!!. The `\varnothing` symbol is horrible!! My god... If I'm honest, I try to use the correct mathematical symbols, but in this case... And you're right. Borbaki (which its original version Hermann-Addison is one of the books with the most beautiful layout of all time for me) uses it.  It makes methink... I have a dilemma...

Comment: *De gustibus non est disputandum*…  Sadly complain poor Scandinavian children who must learn to *read* this letter ;o) B.t.w. this notation was introduced in the mid thirties by André Weil,  one of the founding members of the Bourbaki group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For completeness, I provide the original solution, on the assumption that the font needed is not already loaded by TeX.  Afterward, I show a streamlined solution, since `cmsy` (Computer Modern symbol font family) has already been loaded by default.

The Long Way:

Here, after `mathabx` is loaded, I declare and define the `cmsy` font family, found on p.431 of the TeXbook.  `cmsy` is the name that the Computer Modern symbol font family is known as, to TeX.  It is called a font "family" because the font is provided in different sizes, and `\DeclareFontShape` tells which glyph set (member of the family) to use depending on the fontsize that is requested.

I create a new symbol font `Xcmsy` that points to the `cmsy` font family.  I then declare the symbol `\cmemptyset` to be of category`mathord`, and found in slot 59 of the `Xcmsy` font.

If you uncomment the two `fonttable` lines of code, you will see the cmsy font printed out in tabular form, and can verify that the empty set glyph is found at slot 59.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
% =============================================
%Import symbols from font cmsy without importing the whole package
% =============================================
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {cmsy}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{cmsy}{m}{n}{
  <-8> cmsy7
  <8-9> cmsy8
  <9-10> cmsy9
  <10-> cmsy10}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{Xcmsy} {U} {cmsy}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmemptyset}{\mathord}{Xcmsy}{59}
% =============================================
%\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\centering

$\emptyset \cmemptyset$ 

%\tiny\fonttable{cmsy8}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The Short Way (for Computer Modern only):

Because Computer Modern is already loaded by TeX as the default font, much of the prior method is redundant and the answer can be streamlined (as noted by GuM):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
% =============================================
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmemptyset}{\mathord}{symbols}{59}
% =============================================
\begin{document}
\centering

$\emptyset \cmemptyset$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: could you explain the code, please?

Comment: @Dog_69 I have done so.

Comment: I'm sorry. I expected an explanation after the code. Please excuse me. I haven't seen your body text. My apologies.

Comment: @Dog_69 I edited my answer *after* you asked the initial question.  No need to apologize.  It was a reasonable request.

Comment: Oh! I suppose that explains why I didn't find the explanation. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: There’s no need to re-declare the font family `cmsy` under the `U` encoding, nor to introduce a new symbol font named `Xcmsy`: just say `\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmemptyset}{\mathord}{symbols}{59}` and live happy!  (Doing so amounts exactly to @FranckPastor’s solution.)

Comment: @GuM Thanks.  I figured CM was already loaded, but I wasn't 100% sure of the exact syntax to access it.

Comment: OK, I’ve seen your edit.  But now I feel obliged to add that, of course, this simplified solution works only for a package, like `mathabx`, that does not redefine the `symbols` symbol font; for packages that do redefine it (_e.g._, `newtxmath`), you need the more elaborate solution `\DeclareSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n} \SetSymbolFont{cmsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n} \DeclareMathSymbol{\cmemptyset}{\mathord}{cmsymbols}{59}` (say).  But again, there’s no need to redeclare the `cmsy` font family under a different encoding (`U`, in your case).

Answer (score 4):

The answer below is inspired by the way the author of the `mathabx` package, Anthony Phan, uses to retain the old `\emptyset` symbol (which he calls `\voidset`) while loading his `mathabx` package (see the TeX source of its documentation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\voidset=\emptyset
\usepackage{mathabx}
\let\emptyset=\voidset
\begin{document} 
$\emptyset$   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, why not also `\let\emptyset=\voidset`, then?

Comment: @GuM No particular reason, excepted I was told once to use as few Plain TeX commands as possible in a LaTeX document. It has become an habit since. :-) But indeed, a second `\let` does no harm in this case as far as I see, so I've just inserted it.

Comment: There’s a slight difference in that, with `\let\emptyset=\voidset`, to token `\emptyset` remains unexpandable; but this hardly matters in practice.

Comment: @FranckPastor I thought I replied to yor answer. Anyway. It's a clever idea, very funny, and it is a useful. It is not what I was looking for actually, but I'm sure it will help many people in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`\emptyset` using package `cancel`.
 [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel, amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathabx} 
\begin{document}
\( \cancel{\bigcirc} \)
\end{document}
```